# Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there a more efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array, other than iterating through the contents of said collection and manually pushing each item into an array?

Comment: What is meant by "efficient"? If best performing, a *for* loop is generally faster than *Array.prototype.slice*. A loop also works in a wider variety of browsers (i.e. all), so by those criteria it *is* the "most efficient way". And it's very little code: `for (var a=[], i=collection.length; i;) a[--i] = collection[i];` so not much of a "con" there :-)

Comment: @RobG Thank you - I'd give you +59k if I could! ;-)

Comment: Looking at [*current browser performance*](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-loop-2016), *slice* has mostly caught up with loops in terms of performance, except in Chrome. Using a larger number of elements and slight optimisation of the loop, the [*results are almost identical*](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-loop/11), except in Chrome where a loop is very much faster.

Comment: I created a jsperf test that looks at both methods that @harpo mentioned as well as a jquery test for performance. I've found jquery is slightly slower than both javascript methods and top performance varies between the js test cases. Chrome 59.0.3071 / Mac OS X 10.12.5 prefers using `Array.prototype.slice.call` and Brave (based on Chrome 59.0.3071) has virtually no difference between the two javascript tests over multiple runs.
See https://jsperf.com/htmlcollection-array-vs-jquery-children

Comment: http://jsben.ch/h2IFA => performance test for the most common ways to do this

Comment: If my HTMLCollection includes dynamic links, how do I convert into an array while maintaining the links? When I convert into an array using a for loop, it comes in as text only. I lose the links because of innerHTML

Answer (score 1105, accepted):

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( htmlCollection )
```

will have the same effect using "native" code.

**Edit**

Since this gets a lot of views, note (per @oriol's comment) that the following more concise expression is *effectively* equivalent:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(htmlCollection);
```

But note per @JussiR's comment, that unlike the "verbose" form, it does create an empty, unused, and indeed unusable array instance in the process.  What compilers do about this is outside the programmer's ken.

**Edit**

Since ECMAScript 2015 (ES 6) there is also [*Array.from*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.from):

```
var arr = Array.from(htmlCollection);
```

**Edit**

ECMAScript 2015 also provides the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which is functionally equivalent to `Array.from` (although note that `Array.from` supports a mapping function as the second argument).

```
var arr = [...htmlCollection];
```

I've confirmed that both of the above work on `NodeList`.

A performance comparison for the mentioned methods: http://jsben.ch/h2IFA

Comment: The shortcut `[].slice.call(htmlCollection)` also works.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Yes I was misinformed on that. Sorry for spreading that around. I didn't realize I'd stated that here as well. Deleted the comment to avoid confusion but for context I had read (or misread) somewhere that slicing an HTMLCollection made it behave like both an array and a collection. Totally incorrect.

Comment: Fwiw, the content of Oriol's comment was also mentioned in [@AUTO 's answer, below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22676083/1028230) about a month earlier, if you want to spread the karma around a little.

Comment: The MDN docs for Array.prototype.slice have a nice explanation of when to use this type of conversion and a nice polyfill for Internet Explorer < 9.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: var arr = [].slice.call(htmlCollection); fails in IE 11, but Array.prototype still works

Comment: The [].slice shortcut is not equivalent since it also creates unused empty array instance. Not sure if compilers are able to optimize it away, though.

Comment: `Array.from`, i.e. `from`, is not supported by IE11.

Comment: How does Array.prototype.slice.call( htmlCollection) work? Can anyone here explain?

Comment: @forethought, `Array.prototype.slice` is not normally used this way.  Instead, you would call it as a method on an array like `[3, 5, 7].slice()`.  That creates and returns a new Array based on the indexes passed to `slice`.  When you pass no arguments, it copies the whole array.  HTML collections don't have `Array` in their prototype chain, so you can't use the `slice` method on references to them.  However, if you use `call()` (which is on `Function.prototype`) to invoke `Array.prototype.slice` on an array-like object, it accomplishes the same thing. Hope this helps!

Comment: the spread operator did not work, at least not like this: `[...htmlColl].forEach((i)=>{//do})`

Comment: Spread operator is not working. Type 'HTMLCollection' is not an array type

Comment: Typescript disallow spread operator because htmlCollection doesn't have `[Symbol.iterator]()` method.

Comment: Typescript can't disallow what is unknown: `[... htmlCollection as unknown as Element[]]`

Comment: I get `[]` as result when converting a HTMLColl to Array. The Collection though has elements and can be consolelogged as a whole, but not each element.

Comment: Gist: Array.prototype === []

Comment: These works but in chrome dev-console still shows `typeof(arr)` as object.

Comment: Nice answer, well explained and updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 137):

not sure if this is the most efficient, but a concise ES6 syntax might be:

```
let arry = [...htmlCollection]
```

---

Edit: Another one, from Chris_F comment:

```
let arry = Array.from(htmlCollection)
```

Comment: Additionally, ES6 adds `Array.from()`

Comment: Watch out for the first one, there's a subtle bug when transpiling with babel where [...htmlCollection] will return an array with the htmlCollection as it's only element.

Comment: Array spread operator doesn't work on htmlCollection. It is only applicable to NodeList.

Comment: `Array.from`, i.e. `from`, is not supported by IE11.

Comment: [Benchmark](http://jsben.ch/VqvvR) Looks like the spread operator is faster out of these 2.

Comment: Spread operator is not working. Type 'HTMLCollection' is not an array type

Answer (score 26):

I saw a more concise method of getting `Array.prototype` methods in general that works just as well. Converting an `HTMLCollection` object into an `Array` object is demonstrated below:

```
[].slice.call( yourHTMLCollectionObject );
```

And, as mentioned in the comments, **for old browsers such as IE7 and earlier,** you simply have to use a compatibility function, like:

```
function toArray(x) {
    for(var i = 0, a = []; i < x.length; i++)
        a.push(x[i]);

    return a
}
```

I know this is an old question, but I felt the accepted answer was a little incomplete; so I thought I'd throw this out there FWIW.

Answer (score 7):

For a cross browser implementation I'd sugguest you look at [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) `$A` function

[copyed from 1.6.1](http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js):

```
function $A(iterable) {
  if (!iterable) return [];
  if ('toArray' in Object(iterable)) return iterable.toArray();
  var length = iterable.length || 0, results = new Array(length);
  while (length--) results[length] = iterable[length];
  return results;
}
```

It doesn't use `Array.prototype.slice` probably because it isn't available on every browser. I'm afraid the performance is pretty bad as there a the fall back is a javascript loop over the `iterable`.

Comment: The OP asked for an other way than "iterating through the contents of said collection and manually pushing each item into an array", but that's precisely what the `$A` function does most of the time.

Comment: I think the point I was trying to make is that there isn't a nice way to do it, the prototype.js code shows that you can look for a 'toArray' method but failing that iteration the safest route

Comment: This will create new, undefined members in sparse arrays. There should be a *hasOwnProperty* test before the assignment.

Answer (score 6):

This works in all browsers including earlier IE versions.

```
var arr = [];
[].push.apply(arr, htmlCollection);
```

Since jsperf is still down at the moment, here is a jsfiddle that compares the performance of different methods. https://jsfiddle.net/qw9qf48j/

Comment: try `var args = (htmlCollection.length === 1 ? [htmlCollection[0]] : Array.apply(null, htmlCollection));`

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that **calling `Array.prototype` functions** on instances of `HTMLCollection` is a much better option than converting collections to arrays (e.g.,`[...collection]` or `Array.from(collection)`), because in the latter case a collection is unnecessarily implicitly iterated and a new array object is created, and this eats up additional resources. `Array.prototype` iterating functions can be safely called upon objects with consecutive numeric keys starting from `[0]` and a `length` property with a valid number value of such keys' quantity (including, e.g., instances of `HTMLCollection` and `FileList`), so it's a reliable way. Also, if there is a frequent need in such operations, an empty array `[]` can be used for quick access to `Array.prototype` functions. A runnable example:

```js
alert(
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(
        document.querySelector('ol').children,
        (acc, { textContent }, i) => `${acc}${i + 1}) ${textContent}` + `\n`,
        '',
    ),
);
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>bat</li>
    <li>baz</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 5):

To convert array-like to array in efficient way we can make use of the [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) `makeArray` :

> makeArray: Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array.

Usage:

```
var domArray = jQuery.makeArray(htmlCollection);
```

---

A little extra:

If you do not want to keep reference to the array object (most of the time HTMLCollections are dynamically changes so its better to copy them into another array, This example pay close attention to performance:

```
var domDataLength = domData.length //Better performance, no need to calculate every iteration the domArray length
var resultArray = new Array(domDataLength) // Since we know the length its improves the performance to declare the result array from the beginning.

for (var i = 0 ; i < domDataLength ; i++) {
    resultArray[i] = domArray[i]; //Since we already declared the resultArray we can not make use of the more expensive push method.
}
```

What is array-like?

[HTMLCollection](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) is an `"array-like"` object, the [array-like](http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/) objects are similar to array's object but missing a lot of its functionally definition:

> Array-like objects look like arrays. They have various numbered
>   elements and a length property. But that’s where the similarity stops.
>   Array-like objects do not have any of Array’s functions, and for-in
>   loops don’t even work!

Answer (score 3):

This is my personal solution, based on the information here (this thread):

```
var Divs = new Array();    
var Elemns = document.getElementsByClassName("divisao");
    try {
        Divs = Elemns.prototype.slice.call(Elemns);
    } catch(e) {
        Divs = $A(Elemns);
    }
```

Where $A was described by Gareth Davis in his post:

```
function $A(iterable) {
  if (!iterable) return [];
  if ('toArray' in Object(iterable)) return iterable.toArray();
  var length = iterable.length || 0, results = new Array(length);
  while (length--) results[length] = iterable[length];
  return results;
}
```

If browser supports the best way, ok, otherwise will use the cross browser.

Comment: In general, I don't expect try/catch to be an efficient way to manage control flow. You can check if the function exists first, then run either one or the other a bit cheaper.

Comment: As with Gareth Davis' answer, this creates new, undefined members in sparse arrays, so `[,,]` becomes `[undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: I didn't get this kind of trouble yet. It seams a 3 elements collection results in an array with 2 elements. As for empty become undefined, it's a bit of JavaScript limitations, I gess you were expecting null instead of undefined, right?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, Even You have written code the correct way, But still it doesn't work properly.

```
var allbuttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
console.log(allbuttons);

var copyAllButtons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allbuttons.length; i++) {
  copyAllButtons.push(allbuttons[i]);
}
console.log(copyAllButtons);
```

you get empty array.
Like, This

```
HTMLCollection []
[]
```

[Console_javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKgwq.jpg)

For Solving this problem, You have to add link of javascript file after body tag in html file.

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

As you can see below,
[html_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCTSf.png)

Final Output

```
HTMLCollection(6) [button.btn.btn-dark.click-me, button.btn.btn-dark.reset, button#b, button#b, button#b, button#b, b: button#b]
(6) [button.btn.btn-dark.click-me, button.btn.btn-dark.reset, button#b, button#b, button#b, button#b]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about efficiency but, from a purely aesthetic point of view, I find this pleasing.

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.toArray = function() { return Array.from(this); }
```

now you can use it like this.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tax-status').toArray().forEach(console.log);
```