# Get all LI elements in array

Tags: javascript

How can i make JS select every LI element inside a UL tag and put them into an array?

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="navbar-One">One</li>
        <li id="navbar-Two">Two</li>
        <li id="navbar-Three">Three</li>
        <li id="navbar-Four">Four</li>
        <li id="navbar-Five">Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can i make it so JS gets each of them into an array eg
`navbar['0']` would return `document.getElementById("navbar-One")`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can get a NodeList to iterate through by using [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), like this:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fm5u2/).  This is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) not an array, but it does have a `.length` and you can iterate over it like an array.

Comment: It's important to emphasize: **This is not an array**. It will not behave like an array. If at any point you choose to remove an `LI` element from the HTML, its entry will be "popped" from the collection, everything above it will shift down to fill the space, and the `.length` will decrease. This is not a suitable solution for anyone looking to produce an `array`, and this can only be achieved by iterating through the elements or [converting it to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array).

Answer (score 31):

After some years have passed, you can do that now with ES6 [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)):

```js
const navbar = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#navbar>ul>li'));
console.log('Get first: ', navbar[0].textContent);

// If you need to iterate once over all these nodes, you can use the callback function:
console.log('Iterate with Array.from callback argument:');
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#navbar>ul>li'),li => console.log(li.textContent))

// ... or a for...of loop:
console.log('Iterate with for...of:');
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll('#navbar>ul>li')) {
    console.log(li.textContent);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li id="navbar-One">One</li>
    <li id="navbar-Two">Two</li>
    <li id="navbar-Three">Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: an alternative but seems unnecessarily complex

Comment: The accepted answer calls two DOM methods, while this solution only calls one. The accepted answer does not produce an Array instance, while this answer does, by adding a very readable `Array.from` (I mean: it says what it does, right?). So I don't see why this should be considered "complex".

Answer (score 9):

**QuerySelectorAll** will get all the matching elements with defined selector. Here on the example I've used element's name(`li` tag) to get all of the `li` present inside the div with `navbar` element.

```js
    let navbar = document
      .getElementById("navbar")
      .querySelectorAll('li');

    navbar.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log({ index, item })
    });
```

```html
   
<div id="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li id="navbar-One">One</li>
  <li id="navbar-Two">Two</li>
  <li id="navbar-Three">Three</li>
  <li id="navbar-Four">Four</li>
  <li id="navbar-Five">Five</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the li tags in an array even when they are in different ul tags then you can simply do

```
var lis = document.getElementByTagName('li');
```

and if you want to get particular div tag li's then:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('divID').getElementByTagName('li');
```

else if you want to search a ul first and then its li tags then you can do:

```
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++){
    var lis=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var j=0;j<lis.length;j++){
        console.log(lis[j].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allElmnts = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
var arr = []; 
arr.length = allElmnts.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < allElmnts.length; i++){

    arr[i] = allElmnts[i]; 

}
```