# How to access li elements within ul tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how to access each li within the ul? I am not sure exactly what the name of the ul is.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class= "selectBox-options exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown" style>
    <li class = " omitted">
        more li here omitted
 </ul>
```

My main goal is to have a user click a size in a dropdown lets say size 8 and it will automatically detect that specific li(8) inside the ul

Comment: where is the code ?? I dont see it...

Comment: You want a jQuery solution or not?

Comment: `ul li`? Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @mohkhan should be updated now

Comment: @Brilliand Yes jQuery

Comment: I think you should read the answer of this question : "[Get all LI elements in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019894/get-all-li-elements-in-array)". (you must add an id inside your ul element.)

Comment: @Dallo Is there a way to do that method without adding an Id?

Comment: You could also identify the UL by its class name and/or its parent element.  We can't tell how feasible that is from the information you've given us.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var array_of_li =  document.querySelectorAll("ul.selectBox-options li");
```

If you're not sure that the `ul` will have the `selectBox-options` class, then delete the `.selectBox-options` part - but remember that it will get you every `li` on the page then.

If you're using jQuery, then this is a bit more compatible, and does basically the same thing:

```
var li =  $("ul.selectBox-options li");
```

Comment: So my main objective is for a website that when a user clicks a size lets say 8 it will automatically select that specific li pointing to 8 inside the ul. Is there a way to use .click() with this?

Comment: Look at comment I left above

Comment: Clicks a what?  Yes, click can be used with this, but what the code is like would depend on what is being clicked on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996231/selecting-a-value-from-drop-down-box-using-li-elements-within-ul

Comment: So this is really about a jQuery UI dropdown?  Then you shouldn't be doing what this question is asking at all.  Use the jQuery UI methods to tell the dropdown what value it should be set to.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept jQuery, like you mentioned:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

As the jQuery [`documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) declares.

I'm not sure how to do it with raw javascript though :)

Answer (score 0):

in CSS:

```
li { color:black; }
```

with ul:

```
ul li { }
```

or with class:

```
ul li.ommitted { }
```

or with ul&li class

```
ul.selectBox-options li.ommitted { }
```

ps. Don't forget the end tag

```
</li>
```

Comment: The end tag for `<li>` is optional.

Comment: So it seems, thanks for info. I used to do xhtml, in which you always have to close and have been doing that for nothing after html5. Luckily my IDE auto-comlete html tags, so did not lose much time doing that. Down side is that user lose quite an amount of bandwidth while downloading my optional end tag. Sorry I was not able to answer your question in first place. Hope you get this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style type='text/css'>
      .omitted {
        color:                  rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background:             transparent;
      }

      .selected {
        color:                  rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background:             rgb(0, 0, 0);
      }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function matchSelected(foo) {
        var selectBox =         document.getElementById('selectBox');
        var items =             selectBox.getElementsByTagName('LI');

        for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          items[i].className =  items[i].innerHTML == foo ? 'selected' : 'ommitted';
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>


  <body>


    <ul id='selectBox' class='selectBox-options exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown'>
      <li class='omitted'>1</li>
      <li class='omitted'>3</li>
      <li class='omitted'>8</li>
      <li class='omitted'>10</li>
      <li class='omitted'>14</li>
    </ul>


    <select onChange='matchSelected(this.value);'>
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='3'>Three</option>
      <option value='8'>Eight</option>
      <option value='10'>Ten</option>
      <option value='14'>Fourteen</option>
    </select>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ZjHay/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function(){
        alert($('.selectBox-options li').eq($(this).val()-1).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `select` and the `ul` are siblings inside the same parent element (a `div` for instance), you can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to select the proper `ul` element and its children.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var select = document.querySelector( "#container > select" );
var ul_children = ul_list.querySelectorAll( "#container > select ~ ul > li" );
var selected_li = undefined; // Undefined for now, see below for setting its value.

// If we got results for both select and ul_children.
if ( select !== null && ul_children.length > 0 )
{
    // Map function to the select's "change" event to pick a correct list item.
    select.addEventListener( "change", function( event )
    {
        // Get the select's value after changing the option.
        var selected = select.value;

        // Decrement with 1 to fix offset (ul_children starts from 0).
        selected--;

        // use the select's value to choose the right list item from the li collection.
        selected_li = ul_children.childNodes[ selected ];
    });
}
```

(Above code is probably not cross-browser compatible out of the box, remember to use working code.)

In the above code, we first get the `select` element and the `ul`'s child elements (`li`s). Then we map an anonymous function (could be named too) to the `select`s `change` event (which is triggered each time an option is chosen with it). This function then selects the proper `li` item from the item collection we fetched in line two and assign it to a variable called `selected_li`.

Now you can manipulate and use the `selected_li` however you want.

EDIT: with jQuery this job is probably a bit easier.

Comment: Here is a more detailed example of what I want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996231/selecting-a-value-from-drop-down-box-using-li-elements-within-ul