# Converting parts of a string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have this string:

```
<ol>
    <li><strong>Pro</strong>Something is written here.</li>
    <li>Another one here.</li>
</ol>
```

I need to convert just the contents of the `<li></li>` to an array, if at all possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I’m getting eaten alive for this one.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately... If it's any consolation I haven't downvoted lol... The question seems a little broad and you don't show what you've tried, probably why your question is suffering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all LI elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019894/get-all-li-elements-in-array)

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a DOM parser.

Comment: To be clear, I never mentioned regex in my post. Only added as a tag because I thought it might be used, but it wasn’t a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

For example:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var html = `<ol>
<li><strong>Pro</strong>Something is written here.</li>
<li>Another one here.</li>
</ol>`;
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var listItems = doc.querySelectorAll("ol li");
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    arr.push(listItems[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(arr);
```