# How to find all Siblings of the currently selected DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the perfect way to find all nextSiblings and previousSiblings in JavaScript. I tried few ways but not getting accurate solution. If any element is selected, I need to get length of all next siblings excluding white-space, any spaces or line-breaks.

Also I don't want to use jQuery for this. I am specifically looking something from JavaScript

Comment: So you want to include text nodes that are not empty?

Comment: jQuery != JavaScript. It's legitimate to ask for an answer that isn't wrapped in jQuery obfuscation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'll assume that this takes place inside an event handler where `this` is a reference to the targeted element whose siblings you want to affect.

If not, adjustments will be needed.

```
var result = [],
    node = this.parentNode.firstChild;

while ( node ) {
    if ( node !== this && node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) 
      result.push( node );
    node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling;
}

// result will contain all type 1 siblings of "this"
```

Comment: wow this work great. Thanks a lot. one more question. I am trying to apply webkit style to the result, but animation is not working. any reason?  result.style.webkitTransform='translate(0px,10px)';

Comment: @user - Unfortunately I don't know much about the CSS3 transform property. Try searching SO, and if you can't find an answer, post another question. (Also, please remember to "accept" answers to your questions.)

Comment: i applied loop, but this is working only once. when i clicking again on another object it doesn't work. any reason                                                       for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
var allNextSiblings=result[i];
allNextSiblings.style.webkitTransform='translate(0px, 200px)';

}

Comment: yes sure, your answer really help me a lot. Thanks a lot for the help. I am bit new to java-script.

Comment: @user - Accepting an answer means clicking the large checkmark to the left of the answer. With regard to the issue of it working only once, it likely has something to do with how `webkitTransform` works. I'm not much help there.

Comment: Try WebkitTransform. A dash in CSS means a capital right after: text-align = textAlign; -webkit-transform = WebkitTransform

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work: in my case `node` initially contains a text node (probably some whitespace), so the `while` loop is skipped altogether. Even without empty text nodes, this loop stops when `node === this`, effectively fetching only the *previous* siblings, right?

Comment: Correct, @Niavlys. I have fixed that problem now in an edit.

Comment: Thanks @LOAS for your edit. If it's acceptable I will probably make an edit as well to fix the text nodes issue (which most people will face, I guess).

Answer (score 44):

This is a bit more winded of a solution but allows you to create a filter on how you get siblings.

There are  three functions to get **only** previous, **only** next, or **all**. This could be improved but decent starting point if you need more control on what types of siblings you want to collect. Thought it might be worth adding.

**[Working Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/3CLgK/)**

**get all next siblings**

```
//this will start from the current element and get all of the next siblings

function getNextSiblings(elem, filter) {
    var sibs = [];
    while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
        if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
    }
    return sibs;
}
```

**get all previous siblings**

```
//this will start from the current element and get all the previous siblings

function getPreviousSiblings(elem, filter) {
    var sibs = [];
    while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
        if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
    }
    return sibs;
}
```

**get all siblings**

```
//this will start from the first child of the current element's parent and get all the siblings

function getAllSiblings(elem, filter) {
    var sibs = [];
    elem = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
    do {
        if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // text node
        if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
    } while (elem = elem.nextSibling)
    return sibs;
}
```

**example filter to apply to above functions**

```
// Example filter only counts divs and spans but could be made more complex
function exampleFilter(elem) {
    switch (elem.nodeName.toUpperCase()) {
        case 'DIV':
            return true;
        case 'SPAN':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML and testing output**

HTML

```
<div id='test'>
    <div id='test2'>asdf</div>
    <br /> sdf
    <div>asdfasdf<span>asdf</span></div>
    <div>a</div>
    <span>a</span>
    <br />
    <div>d</div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var elem;
elem = document.getElementById('test2');

//with filter alerts 4
alert( getNextSiblings( elem, exampleFilter ).length );

// no filter, alerts 7
elem = document.getElementById('test2');// put elem back to what it was
alert( getNextSiblings( elem ).length );

// alerts 0
elem = document.getElementById('test2');// put elem back to what it was
alert( getPreviousSiblings( elem, exampleFilter ).length );

// alerts 5
elem = document.getElementById('test2');// put elem back to what it was
alert( getAllSiblings( elem, exampleFilter ).length );
```

Comment: You can get rid of the redundancy in your `getAllSiblings` function by using a `do/while` instead of a `while` loop. A little code reduction might be desirable as well by replacing the `if/else` with an `if` that uses a conditional `||`, as in: `if(!filter || filter( elem )) sibs.push( elem );`

Comment: Those are awesome examples.  I'm confused though on why you needed the "exampleFilter" function.

Comment: It was just a barebones example of what a filter might look like, it's not needed though.

Comment: The `getNextSiblings( elem )` should not be returning 15 elements, there are only 7 in the demo. The reason there are 15 is because it is returning text nodes. If you remove the `!filter || ` from each function, it will ignore text nodes. Also, check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37470381/145346) which uses the `matches` DOM method allowing use of class names & attribute selectors.

Comment: oh wow, yeah... nice catch. Now that the web has progressed ~6 years newer APIs do make things easier :P. One things to note about the matches is i believe IE needs a prefix.

Comment: You can use `previousElementSibling` to filter out the non matching node types

Comment: Thanks @Catalin I'll try to update this to the modern API when I have a moment.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a very short and simple way to do it with ES6:

```
function getAllSiblings(element, parent) {
        const children = [...parent.children];
        return children.filter(child => child !== element);
    }
```

This will return all children of the parent node that are not the element.

Comment: Where is children defined?

Comment: Nice [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). With it and `children.splice(0,1+children.indexOf(element));` you can get all next siblings.

Comment: If you want `ES2015`, just go all the way: `const getSiblings = elm => elm && elm.parentNode && [...elm.parentNode.children].filter(node => node != elm)`

Answer (score 5):

### A simple solution using *ES2015* ([spread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222847/104380) & [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

```js
const getSiblings = (elm, withTextNodes) => {
  if( !elm || !elm.parentNode ) return
  
  let siblings = [...elm.parentNode[withTextNodes ? 'childNodes' : 'children']],
      idx = siblings.indexOf(elm);
  
  siblings.before = siblings.slice(0, idx)
  siblings.after = siblings.slice(idx + 1)
  
  return siblings
}


// Usage example:

const $elm = document.querySelector('em') // target node 
const elmSiblings = getSiblings($elm)

console.log("Siblings Before <em/>:", print(elmSiblings.before))
console.log("Siblings After <em/>:", print(elmSiblings.after))
console.log("All Siblings of <em/>:", print(elmSiblings))

function print(elms){
  return JSON.stringify(elms.map(n => n.tagName || n.textContent))
}
```

```html
<div></div>
text node 1
<a></a>
<p></p>
<em></em>
<main></main>
text node 2
<hr/>
<b></b>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an update to @subhaze's answer.

This code uses the [`matches` DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) which is [supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/m11L82qg/)

```
function matches(elem, filter) {
  if (elem && elem.nodeType === 1) {
    if (filter) {
      return elem.matches(filter);
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// this will start from the current element and get all of
// the next siblings
function getNextSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
    if (matches(elem, filter)) {
      sibs.push(elem);
    }
  }
  return sibs;
}

// this will start from the current element and get all the
// previous siblings
function getPreviousSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
    if (matches(elem, filter)) {
      sibs.push(elem);
    }
  }
  return sibs;
}

// this will start from the first child of the current element's
// parent and get all the siblings
function getAllSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  elem = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
  while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
    if (matches(elem, filter)) {
      sibs.push(elem);
    }
  } 
  return sibs;
}
```

Use these functions as follows:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#test');

// find all the "div" and "span" siblings
var after = getNextSiblings(elem, 'div, span');

// find previous siblings with ".list-item" class
var index = getPreviousSiblings(elem, '.list-item');

// get all siblings with a title attribute
var allSibs = getAllSiblings(elem, '[title]');
```

Answer (score 4):

back to 2017:
Maybe there is a better answer but that good and a little bit cleaner

```
function sibiling(dom, query) {
   var doms = dom.parentElement.querySelectorAll(query);
   return [].slice.call(doms).filter( d => d != dom);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all of the children of the element's parent, and exclude the element itself.

Comment: Yes jquery is javascript :) actually i am working on mobile app and due to its heavy file size i am not using it my code. Actually i have around 50 divs parallel to each other, as per the requirement when i click any div i need to get all next and previous siblings and need to move them to certain position

Comment: @user: When minified and gzipped, jQuery is quite small.

Comment: yes, in mobile safari there are some compatible issues, touch events and animation wont work properly with jquery. HTML 5, Webkit work awesome in mobile environment

Comment: @user: You can use jQuery for selection only, without animation or touch events, and it will still be useful.  Or you can do it manullay as I described.

Answer (score 3):

this is a more shorter solution :

```
let allSiblings = [...elem.parentElement.children].filter(child => child !== elem)];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This answer was previously published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354154/get-siblings-in-javascript-without-libraries/22799266#22799266) in response to a similar question .

**There are a few ways to do it.**

**Either one of the following should do the trick.**

```
// METHOD A (ARRAY.FILTER, STRING.INDEXOF)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
    siblingList = children.filter(function(val) {
        return [node].indexOf(val) != -1;
    });
    return siblingList;
}

// METHOD B (FOR LOOP, IF STATEMENT, ARRAY.PUSH)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
    var siblingList = [];
    for (var n = children.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        if (children[n] != node) {
            siblingList.push(children[n]);
        }  
    }
    return siblingList;
}

// METHOD C (STRING.INDEXOF, ARRAY.SPLICE)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
   siblingList = children;
   index = siblingList.indexOf(node);
   if(index != -1) {
       siblingList.splice(index, 1);
   }
   return siblingList;
}
```

**FYI: The jQuery code-base is a great resource for observing Grade A Javascript.**

**Here is an excellant tool that reveals the jQuery code-base in a very streamlined way.**
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

> All previous siblings

```
// jQuery (optional filter selector)
$el.prevAll($filter);

// Native (optional filter function)
function getPreviousSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
      if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue; // ignore text nodes
      if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
  }
  return sibs;
}
```

> All next siblings

```
// jQuery (optional selector filter)
$el.nextAll($filter);

// Native (optional filter function)
function getNextSiblings(elem, filter) {
        var sibs = [];
        var nextElem = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
        do {
            if (nextElem.nodeType === 3) continue; // ignore text nodes
            if (nextElem === elem) continue; // ignore elem of target
            if (nextElem === elem.nextElementSibling) {
                if (!filter || filter(elem)) {
                    sibs.push(nextElem);
                    elem = nextElem;
                }
            }
        } while(nextElem = nextElem.nextSibling)
        return sibs;
    }
```

*An example of filter function:*

```
function exampleFilter(elem) {
  switch (elem.nodeName.toUpperCase()) {
    case 'DIV':
      return true;
    case 'SPAN':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for non-jQuery answers

Comment: @Machavity, what do you mean, did you even looked at my answer. I provided native JS solution along with old jQuery ones just for the sake of comparison

Answer (score 1):

## This specifically helps you select all siblings of a selected item

This one below actually helped me select ALL SIBLINGS (and that originally excludes the selected item itself) through the PARENT (*the only person who knows your siblings that you don't know is your parent right, its funny that the only ones YOU know are your immediate elder sibling i.e. **previousElementSibling** and immediate younger sibling i.e. **nextElementSibling***). Lol!

### The Code

```
const allSiblings = Array.from(YOUR_SELECTION.parentElement.children)
                         .filter(sibling => sibling.UNIQUE_PropertyName !== (YOUR_SELECTION.COMPARABLE/UNIQUE_PropertyName));

// You don't have to save in a variable if you don't want to
```

### Example

HTML

```
<div id="mummy">
    <div id="baby_1">Samuel</div>
    <div id="baby_2">Dave</div>
    <div id="baby_3">Shaun</div>
    <div id="baby_4">Michael</div>
    <div id="baby_5" class="selected">Fazlullah</div>
    <div id="baby_6">Samson</div>
    <div id="baby_7">Bais</div>
<div>
```

Javascript

```
// I have decide to use the Names of the children as my UNIQUE_Property, So i can get that with the .textContent propertyName 

const selected = document.querySelector('.selected'); // So with "Fazlullah" selected

const allSiblings = Array.from(selected.parentElement.children) // I got to know his mum (.parentElement), then the mum's children(.children)
                         .filter(sibling => sibling.textContent !== selected.textContent); // And this now get's me a list (actually an Array) of his siblings that he doesn't even know.

allSiblings.forEach(sibling => {
    console.log(sibling.textContent);
});
```

If i decide to use the children "id", my chained filter method would have looked: `.filter(sibling => sibling.id !== selected.id);`

See [Demo](https://codepen.io/babblebey/pen/jOPpeKo)

Answer (score 1):

Angular solution to anyone who needs. Can also be edited to plain js

```
getNextSiblings(e: any) {
let element = e as HTMLElement;
let nextSiblings: any[] = [];

let canAdd = false;
element.parentElement?.childNodes.forEach(x => {
  let child = x as HTMLElement;

  if (canAdd) {
    nextSiblings.push(child);
  }

  if (child.id == element.id) {
    canAdd = true;
  }
});

return nextSiblings;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here, I made a couple of functions to get all the previos and the next siblings of any element.

```
const getPreviousAll = element => {
  const previousAllFound = [];
  const getPrevious = element => {
    if (element !== null) {
      previousAllFound.push(element);
      const previousFound = element.previousElementSibling;
      if (previousFound !== null) {
        getPrevious(previousFound);
      }
    }
  };
  getPrevious(element.previousElementSibling);
  return previousAllFound;
};
const getNextAll = element => {
  const target = element;
  const nextAllFound = [];
  const getAll = element => {
    if (element !== null) {
      nextAllFound.push(element);
      const nextFound = element.nextElementSibling;
      if (nextFound !== null) {
        getAll(nextFound);
      }
    }
  };
  getAll(element.nextElementSibling);
  return nextAllFound;
};
```

You just have to call this functions with a node that you can get by getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) along with [`Element.parentNode.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) and [`Element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling):

```js
function* siblingsOf(element) {

  let nextElement = element?.parentNode?.firstElementChild;
  
  while (nextElement !== null && nextElement !== undefined) {
    if (element !== nextElement) {
      yield nextElement;
    }
    nextElement = nextElement.nextElementSibling;
  }

}
```

```js
const mainElement = document.querySelector('main');

for (const element of siblingsOf(mainElement)) {
  console.log(element);
}
```