# How to implement "prevUntil" in Vanilla JavaScript without libraries?

Tags: javascript, dom, siblings

I need to implement the functionality of jQuery's [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) method in Vanilla JavaScript.

I've got several `<div>` elements on the same level:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I'm trying to use an `onclick` event to find the `event.target`'s `previousSiblings` *until* a certain criteria is reached (for example, a class name match) then stop.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @glowcoder: Personally I find it interesting to know what jQuery is actually *doing*.

Comment: @pimvdb, jQuery is open source, don't hesitate to consult its source code if you are interested in what is it actually doing and most importantly *how* is it doing it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I know, I mean that there is nothing wrong with asking what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @pimvdb, no, there is nothing wrong of course.

Comment: I can't use jQuery in the environment I am running this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer was previously published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842336/is-there-a-way-to-select-sibling-nodes/22799075#22799075) in response to a similar question .

**There are a few ways to do it.**

**Either one of the following should do the trick.**

```
// METHOD A (ARRAY.FILTER, STRING.INDEXOF)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
    siblingList = children.filter(function(val) {
        return [node].indexOf(val) != -1;
    });
    return siblingList;
}

// METHOD B (FOR LOOP, IF STATEMENT, ARRAY.PUSH)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
    var siblingList = [];
    for (var n = children.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        if (children[n] != node) {
            siblingList.push(children[n]);
        }  
    }
    return siblingList;
}

// METHOD C (STRING.INDEXOF, ARRAY.SPLICE)
var siblings = function(node, children) {
   siblingList = children;
   index = siblingList.indexOf(node);
   if(index != -1) {
       siblingList.splice(index, 1);
   }
   return siblingList;
}
```

**FYI: The jQuery code-base is a great resource for observing Grade A Javascript.**

**Here is an excellent tool that reveals the jQuery code-base in a very streamlined way.**
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Answer (score 8):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxk7Z/)
Using previousElementSibling:

```
    var className = "needle";
    var element = clickedElement;
    while(element.previousElementSibling && element.previousElementSibling.className != className) {
       element = element.previousElementSibling;
    }
    element.previousElementSibling; // the element or null
```

Comment: This `element.previousSibling.className` is problematical. If no previous sibling has the desired class, `element.previousSibling` will eventually return `null`, so `element.previousSibling.className` will throw an error.

Comment: That was in order to prevent an infinite loop! Just Kidding. I've updated

Comment: Thank you, guy-with-long-name.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.children` in combination with `.parentNode`. Then filter the `NodeList`, after converting it into an array: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/DYSAm/.

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var siblings = [].slice.call(div.parentNode.children) // convert to array
                 .filter(function(v) { return v !== div }); // remove element itself
console.log(siblings);
```

Comment: NodeList to Array casting with `[].slice.call( nl )`? Nice `:)`

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
while ( node = node.previousElementSibling ) {
    if ( ( ' ' + node.className + ' ' ).indexOf( 'foo' ) !== -1 ) {
        // found; do your thing
        break;
    }
}
```

Don't bother telling me that this doesn't work in IE8...

Comment: Would you like to be deceived? Since I won't deceive you I can not answer your question because you asked me not to.

Comment: @Wayne No, I don't like to be deceived. I didn't ask you not to answer my question. Please answer it! And what did I ask? I thought I answered a question, not asked one.

Comment: Sorry misunderstanding on my part. I thought you ment don't tell me it does not work in IE8 literally ... not that you already know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a previousSibling property in the HTML DOM

Here is some reference

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/previousSibling

Comment: The property `previousSibling` is a reference to a DOM node, not a function.

Comment: I understand that completely.  But with some simple iteration you can use this to find the previous element which matches his conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at [how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js).

```
prevUntil: function( elem, i, until ) {
    return jQuery.dir( elem, "previousSibling", until );
},
```

Which uses a while / looping function caled dir(). The prevUntil just keeps going until `previousSibling` is the same as the `until` element.

```
dir: function( elem, dir, until ) {
    var matched = [],
        cur = elem[ dir ];

    while ( cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery( cur ).is( until )) ) {
        if ( cur.nodeType === 1 ) {
            matched.push( cur );
        }
        cur = cur[dir];
    }
    return matched;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `indexOf` to determine if the index of the siblings are less than the index of the target element:

```js
// jshint esversion: 9

// get the target node
const node = document.querySelector("div:nth-child(3)");

// get the target node's index
const node_index = node.parentNode.indexOf(node);

// get the siblings of the target node
const siblings = node => [...node.parentNode.children].filter(child => 
  child !== node
);
console.log(siblings);

// get the prevUntil
const class_name = "\bmy_class\b";
const prevUntil = siblings.filter((sibling, i) =>
  i < node_index && (sibling.getAttribute("class") || "").includes(class_name)
);
console.log(prevUntil);
```

Good luck.