# How read the siblings using java script

Tags: jscript

T read the siblings, children i am using JQuery siblings() and children() method. But due to some restriction I can not use JQuery. So can anyone please let me know that how to achieve this by using java script. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this question have already answer here: [How to find all Siblings of currently selected object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378784/how-to-find-all-siblings-of-currently-selected-object)