# find siblings and addclass using javascript only

Tags: javascript

I want to add class on siblings of target Element in javascript. I have done this before using jquery which is pretty easy. But In my current organization they do not use jquery and I need to done with javascript and that is very difficult for me.

I have write some code that will attached a click function to an matched element but afterward I am not getting any login to how to make it happend. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r19r7djb/4/)

```
var elements= document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
i=0;

while(elements[i]){
    if(elements[i].className=='c'){
        elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(){            
            this.jsSiblings().jsAddClass('newClass')
            })
        }
    i++
}


Array.prototype.jsSiblings= function(){

//code  
}

Array.prototype.jsAddClass=function(){

//code
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: The object returned by `getElementsByTagName()` is not an array, it's a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), and `this` in an event handler usually refers to the HTML element, to which the event has been atached to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the base function in JS to add a class, `element.classList.add("anotherclass");` (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)) and here you will find out about siblings without jQuery : [How to find all Siblings of currently selected object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378784/how-to-find-all-siblings-of-currently-selected-object)

Comment: Can we do it with prototype methods

Comment: @amit Why you assume JavaScript `Array` would be in the prototype chain of an HTML element? It is not.

Comment: You will have to get help from someone else around, as I'm really not used to this way of doing. As for the array/collection, function `getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList` according to the spec, which is not an array (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094).

Comment: @Teemu: I thought it is part of array. So now how do we attached proptotype chain in Html collection or html element