# Make all selected css circles active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a progress bar of css circles, in which after clicking on every circle like 1, 2, 3 all the three circles and their connected line will be filled by red color and if go back like 3, 2, 1 then color should be removed.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row well" id="rows">
        <ul id="progressbar" class="progressbar">
            <li class="cir danger">THOUGHFUL</li>
            <li class="cir">PASSION</li>
            <li class="cir">POWER OF DESIGN</li>
            <li class="cir">BUILDING RELATIONSHIPS</li>
            <li class="cir">ENHANCE HUMAN INTERATION</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS :**

```
var header = document.getElementById("rows");
        var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar");
        var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("cir");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                var danger = document.getElementsByClassName("danger");
                danger[0].className = danger[0].className.replace("danger", "");
                this.className += " danger";
            });
        }
```

**Sample Img:**
[image]

Referring to above imag, if i click on circle 3 then circle 1,2,3 should be in red color and then if i click circle 2 then circle 3 should be white and 1 & 2 should be red, vice versa.
I have tried to achieve it by JS but `classnotfound` error .

Any help for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full error

Comment: now there is no error, wrong classname i have added, now the filling by red color is not worlking

Comment: You need to target the previous siblings and next siblings to ensure previous siblings get coloured and any siblings after are decoloured. For help on targeting previous and next siblings, refer to [How to find all Siblings of the currently selected DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378784/how-to-find-all-siblings-of-the-currently-selected-dom-object).

Comment: Also, is the GIF just meant to be you moving the cursor, because it doesn't seem to be any more helpful than an image?

Comment: yes that gif is not working here, i've converted video to gif, i have through the link you shared but how can i make them colored can you please about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a circle is clicked, grab its data-id and activate all circles of an equal or lesser data-id.

```js
let circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle")
circles.forEach(el => {
   el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     let id = e.target.dataset.id
     circles.forEach(el2 => {
        if(el2.dataset.id <= id){
            el2.classList.add("active")
        }else{
            el2.classList.remove("active")
        }
     })   
   })
})
```

```css
.circled{display:flex}
.circle{
   border-radius:50%;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border: solid 2px #333;
   display:inline-flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
   position:relative;
   margin-left: 44px;
   cursor:pointer;
}

.circle:not(:first-of-type)::before{
   height: 2px;
   width: 50px;
   content:"";
   background-color: #333;
   position:absolute;
   left:-50px;
}

.circle.active{
   border-color: #f00;
}

.circle.active:not(:first-of-type)::before{
   background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
   <div class="circle active" data-id="1">1</div>
   <div class="circle" data-id="2">2</div>
   <div class="circle" data-id="3">3</div>
   <div class="circle" data-id="4">4</div>
   <div class="circle" data-id="5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we make circle 1 red by default.

Comment: @PrathameshDoke see my edit, I just added "active" to the first circle's class

Answer (score 1):

Not proud of this

```
var header = document.getElementById("rows");
var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("cir");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns,function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    updateProgress(btn,e)
  })
});

function updateProgress(btn,e){
    removeDangerFromAll();

  for( let btnToCheck of btns){
    btnToCheck.classList.add('danger');

    if (btnToCheck == btn) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function removeDangerFromAll(){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns,function(btn){
    btn.classList.remove('danger');
  });
}
```

**UPDATE: Switched to cleaner classList as Other Answer**

Comment: Thanks,for the answer @Shaun it is working but when click the previous sibling its color does not change.

Comment: any chance of your CSS, or a jsfiddle?