# results.shift is not a function: firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've written this code in Firefox JS extension

```
var results = gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("b-serp-item__title-link");

alert(results.length);
var countToDelete = results.length - 10;
alert(countToDelete);
if (countToDelete > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < countToDelete; i++);
    {
        alert("I prepare");            
        results.shift();
        alert("I done");
    }
}
alert("succ");
```

And I've got this output

results.length=12
countToDelete=2
(I prepare)

and... that's all
There is a problem at results.shift();
I looked in Firefox Error Console and I found this

"results.shift is not a function"

Why? Is shift a js function?
When I try to run this code in firefox console I've got this error again

What's the matter?

My version of Firefox is 4.
Tested url is http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&lr=37

Comment: No, it's much like an array: it has a length, and you can get elements of it using `collection[0]`, `collection[1]`, etc. but it's not actually an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will convert your `nodelist` to a real `Array`, which has a usable `shift` method:

```
var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(
                gBrowser
                   .contentDocument
                   .getElementsByClassName("b-serp-item__title-link")
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clear that there is no such thing as `shift()` in Gecko:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList

The main question is what you want to achieve by it? By removing items form the `NodeList` you are certainly not removing them from the DOM document. What is your quarrel with `removeChild()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the HTMLCollection to an array if you want to use shift() :

[Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)