# Can't copy array of buttons in a different array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cant understand why this does not store a copy of the previous array.

code

```
console.log(buttons);

var copybtns = [];
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
copybtns = buttons[i];
    
}

console.log(copybtns);
```

and I get this in my console
[image]

My dull html code

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="">
            <select name="changecolor" id="background" onchange="changeToRed(this)">
                <option value="Random">Random</option>
                <option value="Red"">Red</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="Black">Black</option>
                <option value="Reset">Reset</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <button>0</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">1 </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">3</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">4</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was watching a tutoprial but wrote the same code but i don't know why its not working

I want a result like this
[image]

Comment: try `copybtns.push(buttons[i]);` - If it does not work please add your HTML to debug further

Comment: Be aware that this does not copy the actual *buttons*. Use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) if you want to actually copy those as well.

Comment: Why not simply `const copybtns = Array.from(buttons);`?

Comment: `copybtns[i] = buttons[i];` inside the for loop would also fix it.

Comment: @Justin Add your HTML - and whats you expected output ?

Comment: I ran your code with the HTML you gave us but `copybtns` returns the last button instead of `[]`...

Comment: my html code  `<button>0</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">1 </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">3</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">4</button>`

Comment: i tried push , Array.from , [...buttons]

Comment: @Justin you still having issues ?

Comment: console.log(copybtns); should be same as console.log(buttons);

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes

Comment: @Justin See the answer below. It working and showing `console.log(copybtns); should be same as console.log(buttons);`

Comment: You got a lot of valid possibilities/answers for your problem. What's not working for you with these suggestions? Are you looking to also log a `HTMLCollection` for the copy?

Comment: @OlivierKrull yes

Comment: Looks like you got your answer even if it's not returning a `HTMLCollection`. Here are some links about the differences: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770147/is-htmlcollection-an-array). Also I just saw your image in the question. The result you're looking for also isn't a `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: In turn it's still not clear to me what you're looking for. Do you want just an `Array` containing the button elements references or a `HTMLCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `forEach` function using `querySelectorAll` method to store the button in your empty array `copybtns`

> Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/efxwbtyu/

```js
//get all buttons
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

//Original buttons
console.log(buttons)

//store
var copybtns = [];

//foreach
buttons.forEach((data) => copybtns.push(data))

//log the array data
console.log(copybtns);
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">1 </button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning">4</button>
```

Comment: but this is the result I get`NodeList []
length: 0
__proto__: NodeList
main.js:14 
[]
length: 0`

Comment: @Justin It should work fine. Just like it working in my answer above. I am not sure what is this result ?

Comment: @Justin I saw your image above regarding expected results. So you want it like that. I have edited my answer. My `console.log(copybtns)` above in the answer is showing exactly the results you wanted in the picture in your question. Also the js fiddle demo is showing the same results as you wanted in the console.

Comment: Okay I will just make a new project and try again. Thank you so much for the help]