# how to get multiple selected values and items from listbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, html-select

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function getValue()
    {
      var x = document.getElementById("sel");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
          if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
              alert(x.options[i].selected);
          }
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="sel">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getValue()"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my code. How do I get all the selected values from a listbox using JavaScript? The above code is showing `true` for all the selected values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace

```
  if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
      alert(x.options[i].selected);
  }
```

with

```
  if(x.options[i].selected){
      alert(x.options[i].value);
  }
```

Comment: It's useless to use `if(x.options[i].selected==true)` instead of `if(x.options[i].selected)`, but it could make sense `if(x.options[i].selected===true)` or `if(!!x.options[i].selected)`

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you do it using jQuery like this:

```
var selected = $('#sel option:selected');
```

If you prefer not to use jQuery then disregard this answer and refer to the other ones.

Comment: Question asks for a JavaScript solution and is not tagged *jQuery*

Comment: @Phil Just making a suggestion, the user can disregard it if he doesn't use jQuery, but also it may present to him easy DOM access he may consider.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/: "*Because `:selected` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:selected` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:selected` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":selected")`*". Therefore `var selected = $('#sel option').filter(':selected');` is better.

Answer (score 3):

use ***selectedOptions***

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    alert(x.selectedOptions[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with the same example

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function getValue()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("sel");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
            if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                alert(x.options[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="sel">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getValue()"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers that support ECMAScript 2015 you can use

`let selectedValues = Array.from(multiSelectElement.options).filter(o=>o.selected).map(o=>o.value)`

or (using the spread operator)

`let selectedValues = [...multiSelectElement.options].filter(o=>o.selected).map(o=>o.value)`

For antique browsers like Internet Explorer and for extreme backwards compatibility you can still do it the long way:

```
var selectedValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < multiSelectElement.options.length; ++i) {
    var option = multiSelectElement.options[i];
    if (option.selected) {
        selectedValues.push(option.value);
    }
}
```

where `multiSelectElement` is a reference to the `select` element (use `document.getElementById("sel")` or whatever)

Reference:
[Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)

Full example:

```js
function getValues() {
  let multiSelectElement = document.getElementById("sel");
  let selectedValues = Array.from(multiSelectElement.options).filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value);
  console.log(selectedValues);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Windows desktop browsers: Use CTRL+Click or SHIFT+Click to select multiple options
  </p>
  <select multiple id="sel">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Get Values" onclick="getValues()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is very simple **replace this function with your old function**

```
function getValue() {
        var x = document.getElementById("sel");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
            if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                alert(x.options[i].value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = document.querySelectorAll('#sel option:checked');
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [obj[key].value, obj[key].text]);
alert(result);
```

The above is jQuery solution, in case somebody like me searches for javascript solution but decides to go with jQuery.