# how to get value from list box in html

Tags: html, listbox

This is an example,

```
<select>
    <option value=1>Cars</option>
</select>
```

How i can get the value of selected "1" and value in list box "Cars"?

Comment: I believe that you have to use either submit a form or use some Javascript in order to access those values.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1911676) for an idea of how to use Javascript to get the values you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775912/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-and-items-from-listbox-using-javascript/77586331#77586331

Answer (score 3):

try out this

```
<select id="selectID">
    <option value=1>Cars</option>
</select>
```

using javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectID");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#sltbox").find("option[value=1]").attr("selected","selected")
```

Give id as sltbox to your select tag.

Comment: Where was jQuery (or JavaScript) mentioned?

Comment: Then add selected attribute directly to your option tag. like this <option value=1 selected>1</option

Comment: @Blender - you can't be serious. You expect to perform conditional action only in markup? Even Angular is syntactic sugar that ties to Javascript.

Comment: @pmont: There's not enough information to even tell what language OP is working with.