# Send multiple values from select dropdown to text box using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to push array values from multiple select dropdown into text box on clicking "Add" using getElementById

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 TextName: <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" />
 Name:<select multiple="" name="ddlNames[]" id="ddlNames">
<option value="Mudassar Khan">Mudassar Khan</option>
<option value="John Hammond">John Hammond</option>
<option value="Mike Stanley">Mike Stanley</option>
</select>
<button onclick="SetName()">Add</button>

<script>
function SetName() {
        var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
    txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames[]").value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code outputs only the first selected option to the textbox but not all the selected options.Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Or what I can change?

Comment: This should show you how to get all selected options ► [how to get multiple selected values and items from listbox using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775912/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-and-items-from-listbox-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all selected values of a multiple select box using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

To get all the selected options you can iterate through all options and then you can filter only the selected one. Take a look on the below snippet.

```
 Array.prototype.filter.call( document.getElementById("ddlNames").options, el => el.selected).map(el => el.value).join(",")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  TextName:
  <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" /> Name:
  <select multiple="" name="ddlNames[]" id="ddlNames">
    <option value="Mudassar Khan">Mudassar Khan</option>
    <option value="John Hammond">John Hammond</option>
    <option value="Mike Stanley">Mike Stanley</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="SetName()">Add</button>

  <script>
    function SetName() {
      var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
      txtName.value = Array.prototype.filter.call( document.getElementById("ddlNames").options, el => el.selected).map(el => el.value).join(",");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Solution 2**

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get only selected options

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  TextName:
  <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" /> Name:
  <select multiple="" name="ddlNames[]" id="ddlNames">
    <option value="Mudassar Khan">Mudassar Khan</option>
    <option value="John Hammond">John Hammond</option>
    <option value="Mike Stanley">Mike Stanley</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="SetName()">Add</button>

  <script>
    function SetName() {
      var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
      var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#ddlNames option:checked");
      txtName.value = Array.prototype.map.call(selected, el => el.value).join(',');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: welcome , we ca accept the answer -->  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

the id  is `ddlNames` and not `ddlNames[]`.
Change to the following;

```
function SetName() {
      var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
      txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a `+`
`txtName.value += document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;`

```js
function SetName() {
    var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
    txtName.value += document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 TextName: <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" />
 Name:<select multiple="" name="ddlNames" id="ddlNames">
<option value="Mudassar Khan">Mudassar Khan</option>
<option value="John Hammond">John Hammond</option>
<option value="Mike Stanley">Mike Stanley</option>
</select>
<button onclick="SetName()">Add</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) instead to query all checked option DOM, then get the value of each element by a `for-loop`.

**For example:**

```
function SetName() {
        var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
        var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#ddlNames option:checked");
        var values = [];
        for(var i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
                    values.push(selected[i].value);
                }
    txtName.value = values.join(',');
}
```