# How to use array methods on document.links array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why `pop()` method does not work?
I have this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can I use array methods on documents links to remove or add elements?
Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>
<body>
<div>
<nav class="mainNav" id="mainNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New-age_music" title="New Age"  target="_blank" > New Age </a> 
<ul class=subNav>
<li><a href="DevaPremal.html" title="Deva Premal" target="_blank"> Deva Premal</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.karuneshmusic.com/" title="Karunesh" target="_blank">Karunesh</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.luboistok.ru/" title="Oles" target="_blank">Oles</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addLinks()
{
    var allLinksArray = document.links;
    var singersArray = allLinksArray.pop();
    console.log(allLinksArray.length);
    console.log(singersArray.length);
}

addLinks();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because document.links returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not a simple array.
So you need to convert HTMLCollection to real array.

An example how to do this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array).

You need:

```
var allLinksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.links );
```

All for you - even working code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RR2ec/) ;)

Comment: Or the shorter `[].slice.call(document.links)`

Comment: Right, but with `Array` it is more easy to understand :)