# How to add a class, one by one, to each element in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to add a class to each element in a list(specifically the `<a>` in the list items), but one at a time. I am doing this because the `<a>` have a CSS transition on them and I want to have them animate one at a time. So item1 animates, then item2 animates, then item3 animates... Here is what I could attempt to come up with so far.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>item1</a></li>
    <li><a>item2</a></li>
    <li><a>item3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery/js:

```
animateItems();
function animateItems(){
       $('ul li a').each(function() {
          $(this).addClass('animate'); //This doesn't run one at a time
       });
    }
```

I feel like this is leading in the direction of recursion, but not sure really.

**update:** I just realized that this may be harder than i thought because jQuery needs to know about the css transition time doesnt it? **Is there a way to add the classes with a setTimeout() until it begins the next addClass()?** Does each() create an array or jQuery object that I can iterate through?

Comment: You can read the transition attribute using JS to adjust the delay accordingly.

Comment: @mvp I didnt know that this could be done. thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `setTimeout` function:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(i, el) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $(el).addClass('...');
   }, i * 1000);
});
```

The above code assumes that the CSS animation duration is 1s. You can change it accordingly!

And a note: `this` in the context of the `setTimeout` callback function doesn't refer to the current element. You should either cache the `this` object of the `each` callback or use the second parameter of the `each` callback which refers to the current element in the set.

Comment: dang, you beat me by a whisker

Comment: @vohuman so just for the sake of understanding; the i is the index of the array-like object that each() creates and the el is similar to this? I know el =/= this, but its similar?

Comment: @NilsR Both `el` and `this` value of the `each`  callback refer to the same element.

Answer (score 3):

Why not put the animation duration in a variable and use `setTimeout`?

```
var animationDuration = 2000; // 2000 millieseconds

function animateItems(){
   $('ul li a').each(function(i, item) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(item).addClass('animate');
      }, i * animationDuration); // this multiplies the index by the duration so the handler is fired in sequence
   });
}
```

Another option would be to use the [JavaScript Animation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events).

Comment: @RickHitchcock just noticed that :-)

Answer (score 2):

in javascript, you'll usually use the setTimeout and setInterval functions when you want to schedule code to be run in the future, but there are no blocking instructions like "Thread.Sleep"

```
animateItems();
function animateItems(){
   $('ul li a').each(function(i) {

       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(i);
           $(this).addClass('animate'); //This doesn't run one at a time
       }, i * 1000);

   });
}
```

Comment: Note that `this` refers to the window in this context.

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) can make an [HTMlCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which cannot be directly iterated with for/in loops, but [foreach loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements) may provide some insight. [To turn the HTMLCollection into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array), reference here. Unfortunatly I'm not familiar with these collections and can't say much.

After you have an array iterating over them should be easy. Apply each animation, including [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).