# Javascript / Sort object array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have created an 5x2 `<table>`  with `id="competitors"`.

[image]

I am trying to sort the competitors as objects **by their position** property(`pos`) with the following code if `onclick="sortData()"` event happens:

```
function getTableData() {
  var tab = document.getElementById("competitors");
  var data = [];

  for(var i=0;i<tab.rows.length;i++) {
    var competitor = {
        name: tab.rows[i].cells[0],
        pos: tab.rows[i].cells[1]
    };

    data.push(competitor);
  }

  return data; 
}

function sortData() {
  var sortedData = getTableData();
  sortedData.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt(a.pos) - parseInt(b.pos);
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < sortedData.length;i++) {
    console.log(sortedData[i].name.innerHTML, sortedData[i].pos.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the console prints out the same table. However, if i do not add the compare function, it is sorted alphabetically. Please help me to understand what is going on. (i have started JS yesterday )

Comment: Sorting it makes no changes to the DOM, you need to make those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sorting, you were doing `parseInt` of HTML elements instead of their contents.
Here is how I would do it:

```js
function sortData(){
  var table = document.getElementById('competitors'),
      data  = [].slice.call(table.rows);

  data.sort(function(a,b){
      return parseInt(a.cells[1].innerHTML, 10) - parseInt(b.cells[1].innerHTML, 10);
  });

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      table.appendChild(data[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
td{ border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center; padding: .2em }
```

```html
<table id="competitors">
  <tr><td>Greg</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>John</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sarah</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Ben</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Jack</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="sortData()">Sort</button>
```

> **What's `[].slice.call(table.rows)` for?**
>
> `table.rows` returns an HTMLCollection, which cannot be sorted. This allows you to convert it to an Array -> [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)
>
> **Why use `appendChild`?**
>
> When you do `appendChild` of an element, it does not duplicate it, it moves it. This allows you to reorder your elements.