# Using JavaScript to filter/search table

Tags: javascript, search, filter

First of all, I'm not an expert in JavaScript, so the answer will probably be simple, but currently I'm using this (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) tutorial to filter through a table, but you can only search in 1 column, so in this example only for Name or Country, but I want to search in both columns at the same time.

What do I need to change in this code?

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // This code only get the frist "TD" element
        tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            td = tds[j];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to an Array ([check this answer for ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)) and then use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if 'some' of the `td`values match your `filter`. If there is a match, display them. Else hide them. Here's the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById('myInput')
  const filter = input.value.toLowerCase()
  const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  const tr = [...table.getElementsByTagName('tr')]

  tr.forEach((t) => {
    const foundMatch = [...t.getElementsByTagName('td')].some((td) => {
      return td.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
    })
    if (foundMatch) {
      t.style.display = ''
    } else {
      t.style.display = 'none'
    }
  })
}
```

Check it in action on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marcusmonteiro/hsdyajbn/2/show/