# How do I convert a HTMLCollection into an array, without emptying it?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am trying to convert an HTMLCollection of 4 divs into an array, but every method I try seems to result in the array being emptied.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="shape" id="one"></div>
        <div class="shape" id="two"></div>
        <div class="shape" id="three"></div>
        <div class="shape" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Methods I've attempted - as per [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array):

```
var shapesHC = document.getElementsByClassName('shape');
//gives HTMLCollection

var shapesArrCall = [].slice.call(shapesHC);
// returns empty array

var shapesArrHC = Array.from(shapesHC);
// returns empty array

var shapesArrHCSpread = [...shapesHC];
// returns empty array
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: All three of those methods return a non-empty array when I tested it. Perhaps your problem is somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Thanks for quick response - this is the entirety of my code.  It's just one html file and a js file.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript in your code located, above or below your HTML?  If it is above your HTML (in the head), those elements don't exist to be queried until **after** your JavaScript has run.

Comment: Read this question and see if it applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/691711

Comment: Yep, my script tag was in the head.  Now that I've moved it to the end of the body it works fine.  *Facepalm*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.convertToArray();
});

convertToArray() {
    const shapesHC = document.getElementsByClassName('shape');
    const shapesArrHCSpread = [...(shapesHC as any)];
    console.log(shapesArrHCSpread);
}
```

Comment: Why it worked with setTimeout?