# Using Array class methods for HTMLCollection DOM traversel in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to avoid using jQuery for DOM manipulation. I prefer to use ES6 features. ES6 has a robust array class, so I am considering converting HTMLCollection objects into arrays and then parsing them using the Array class:

```
actual = [ '10/12/2018', 'Affidavit', 'Party', 7 ];
collection = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelector('#tblEvents').rows )
target_row = collection.find(function(row){
  predicate = row.cells[0].innerText.trim() == actual[0] && row.cells[1].innerText.trim() == actual[1] && row.cells[4].innerText.trim() == actual[3];
  if(predicate){
    if(actual[2] !== null && actual[2] !== ''){
      return actual[2] == row.cells[2].innerText.trim();
    } else {
      return true;
    } 
  }

  return false;
})
```

The es6 method I am using here is **find()**. But HTMLCollection has no such method.

Is this the appropriate solution for ES6 or does the HTMLCollection class offer something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to convert it to an array first with `Array.from`:

```
const collection = Array.from(document.querySelector('#tblEvents').rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to simply manipulate the DOM you are OVER complicating things.

ES6 does not add anything new for DOM manipulation... As for jQuery it is simply a library that makes things easier for you (also normalizes different behavior between browsers).

DOM manipulation - searching, adding, deleting and editing elements from the page.

selecting a DOM element can be done using one of the following

1. document.querySelector();
2. doucment.querySelectorAll();
3. document.getElementById();
4. document.getElementsByClassName();
5. document.getElementsByName();
6. document.getElementsByTagName();

Editing:

```
let element = document.querySelector();
element.innerHTML = "Hello World";
element.setAttribute('data-custom', 123);
```

Deleting:

```
document.removeChild(childNode);
```

You can read more at:

[The HTML DOM Element Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

[Document Object Properties and Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of converting a collection to an array is using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const collection = [...document.querySelector('#tblEvents').rows];
```

There is this question about the most efficient way of concerting an HTMLCollection to an Array discussing the various ways:
[Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)