# Uncaught TypeError: topics.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get an output of my array.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

    var isExpanded = false;
    sidebar.classList.forEach(function(className) {
        if (className == 'expand') {
            isExpanded = true;
        }
    });

    if (isExpanded) {
        sidebar.classList.remove('expand');
    } else {
        sidebar.classList.add('expand');
    }

    isExpanded = !isExpanded;



    var contentwrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');


    if (isExpanded) {
        contentwrapper.classList.add('padding-offset-2');

    } else {
        contentwrapper.classList.remove('padding-offset-2');
    }


    var topics = document.getElementById("content-wrapper").children;
    console.log(topics);
    topics.forEach(function(topic) {

        console.log(topic);

    })

});
```

I am getting the error, that topics.forEach is not a function. Can someone help me with that? I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I am trying to learn JS atm. :)

Comment: Please fix your code

Comment: Give us the output of your `console.log(topics);` I assume that your `topics` is not an array.

Comment: You're trying to iterate through a list of children that don't exist. You could make the code typesafe and declare `topics && topics.forEach` but either way your application is pointless, crashed due to type error or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topics = document.getElementById("content-wrapper").children;
```

`topics` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array, and therefore does not have a forEach() method. You need to [convert it to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) first.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var topics = document.getElementById("content-wrapper").children;
   console.log(topics);
```

topics give collection of HTMLCollection, Convert it to array.

see this [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)

```
  var topics= [].slice.call(topics);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each would not work.
try using class for the selector.

```
$.each( topic, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
 // do your stuff here
});
```

OR

```
$(".content-wrapper").each(function() {
  // do your stuff here
});
```