# Why is Array.from returning [object HTMLParagraphElement] not the content within the paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am trying to get Javascript to read and write a paragraph based on content elsewhere on the page (specifically the names of items in a cart summary). The problem is that I can't get Javascript to write them correctly.

I need the being written paragraph to be "Order Includes: Product 1, Product 2, etc." but instead it is returning "Order Includes: [object HTMLParagraphElement], [object HTMLParagraphElement], etc."

```
<!-- Cart Summary -->
<p class="cartitems" id="Quantity">Product 1</p>
<p class="cartitems" id="Quantity">Product 2</p>

<!-- Paragraph to be written -->     
<p id="printItems"></p>

<script>
  var prods = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems");
  var items = Array.from(prods);
  document.getElementById("printItems") = "Order Includes: " + 
  items;
</script>
```

I've tried using

```
var prods = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems").innerHTML;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("printItems").innerHTML = "Order Includes: " + 
  items;
```

But both return undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns a collection of DOM elements. When you convert the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), returned by the method, to an array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), use the callback to get the innerText from the elements:

```js
var prods = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems");
var items = Array.from(prods, el => el.innerText);
document.getElementById("printItems").innerHTML = "Order Includes: " +
  items.join(', ');
```

```html
<!-- Cart Summary -->
<p class="cartitems" id="Quantity">Product 1</p>
<p class="cartitems" id="Quantity">Product 2</p>

<!-- Paragraph to be written -->
<p id="printItems"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What `document.getElementsByClassName` is returning is an HTMLCollection
([HMTLCollection MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection))

This is a direct element which is part of the DOM. So you can not parse it directly to an array, you can use the following method to parse to your desired array:

`var prods = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems");
var parsedArray = Array.from([].slice.call(prods));
document.getElementById("printItems") = "Order Includes: " + 
  items;`

As suggested on Harpo response ([Harpo response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array))

NOTE: using Array.from on this case would be optional because what slice returns is an array by its own.