# Indexing an HtmlCollection or NodeList

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, htmlcollection

I am trying to clone a node that is a child of another node, however js is not letting me index the HTMLCollection/NodeList datatype. Whenever I try to index that datatype it always results in an undefined value. Even when I convert that datatype to an array as per [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) I am still not able to index the array.

```
var viewports = document.getElementsByClassName('imageViewerViewport');
console.log(viewports[0].childNodes)  // In the console shows the children I expect to see
console.log(viewports[0].childNodes.item(0))  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log(viewports[0].childNodes.item(1))  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log(viewports[0].children.item(0))  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log(viewports[0].children.item(1))  // Nothing shows up  - undefined    
console.log(viewports[0].childNodes[0])  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log(viewports[0].childNodes[1])  // Nothing shows up  - undefined    
console.log(viewports[0].children[0])  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log(viewports[0].children[1])  // Nothing shows up  - undefined
console.log("Here")
var second_canvas = viewports[0].children.item(1).cloneNode(true);  // Error that is detailed below
viewports[1].appendChild(second_canvas);
```

Error that cloning the node gives: `Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you post your sample HTML

Comment: All the HTML is automatically generated by JS.

Comment: Use inspect in Chrome, copy out the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that not ALL `childNodes` are valid `Node`
Here is a verbose version, where we log to show the invalid nodes.

```js
const cloneThings = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.cloneMyChildren').forEach(parentNode => {
    console.log(parentNode.classList.length);
    parentNode.childNodes.forEach(child => {
      console.log(child.outerHTML); // This is here to show, the child nodes are NOT all HTMLElements.
      if(child.outHTML) {
        const childClone = child.cloneNode(true);
        childClone.classList.add('clone');
        document.body.appendChild(childClone);
      }
    });
  });
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('button')) {
    cloneThings();
  }
});
```

```css
.cloneMe {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clone {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<button>Clone Stuff</button>
```

Here is a more concise version.

```js
const cloneThings = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cloneMyChildren'))
       .flatMap(p => Array.from(p.childNodes).filter(c => c.outerHTML !== undefined))
       .forEach(n => {
          const childClone = n.cloneNode(true);
          childClone.classList.add('clone');
          document.body.appendChild(childClone);       
       });
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('button')) {
    cloneThings();
  }
});
```

```css
.cloneMe {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clone {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<div class="cloneMyChildren">
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>
  <span class="cloneMe">Clone Me</span>  
</div>
<button>Clone Stuff</button>
```