# Method skips an item when appending to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a class with methods to extract and process text from html. The html file contains three articles. Each in a 'text' tag. The 'getArticles' method extracts all the text elements and creates an object. Then, the 'getTexts' method is supposed to take the text from the object and render it to html. BUT it just keeps skipping the text from the article in the middle, starting with 'Set in Australia...'. I have tried to remove another article from the html and then the missing article appeared, but it just wont include all three articles together. Help?

```js
DOM = {
    output1: document.querySelector('.output1')
};


class TextAnalyzer {

    
    getArticles = (out) => {
        this.articles = document.getElementsByTagName("text");
    }

    getText = (key) => {
         return this.articles[key];
    }

   
    getTexts = (out) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.articles);
        console.log(keys);
             
        keys.forEach(key => {
            console.log(this.articles[key])
            out.appendChild(this.articles[key])
        })
            
    }

    showArticles = () => console.log(this.articles);
}

const analysis = new TextAnalyzer();
analysis.getArticles();
analysis.showArticles();
analysis.getTexts(DOM.output1);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0001 </docno>
            <docid> 1 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Book Review; Page 1; Book Review Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            1206 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            NEW FALLOUT FROM CHERNOBYL; 
            </p>
            <p>
            THE SOCIAL IMPACT OF THE CHERNOBYL DISASTER BY DAVID R. MARPLES (ST. MARTIN'S 
            PRESS: $35, CLOTH; $14.95, PAPER; 316 PP., ILLUSTRATED; 0-312-02432-0) 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <byline>
            <p>
            By James E. Oberg , Oberg, a space engineer in Houston, is the author of 
            Uncovering Soviet Disasters: Exploring the Limits of Glasnost (Random House). 
            </p>
            </byline>
            <text>
            <p>
            The onset of the new Gorbachev policy of glasnost, commonly mistranslated as 
            openness but closer in connotation to candor or publicizing, has complicated 
            the task of Soviet secret-keepers and has allowed substantial new Western 
            insights into Soviet society. David R. Marples' new book, his second on the 
            Chernobyl accident of April 26, 1986, is a shining example of the best type of 
            non-Soviet analysis into topics that only recently were absolutely taboo in 
            Moscow official circles. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The author, a British-educated historian and economist, is a research associate 
            with the Canadian Institute of Ukrainian Studies at the University of Alberta, 
            and the academic style of the book is undisguised. However, its intended 
            audience is the general public, and anyone interested in nuclear power, or 
            Soviet economy and society, or human drama, or just plain sleuthing state 
            secrets, will find hitherto unpublished revelations and explanations of the 
            event and its continuing aftermath. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The effects of Chernobyl reverberated throughout so many facets of Soviet 
            society that a continuous coherent narrative is probably impossible. Marples 
            discusses half a dozen major themes arranged in a fairly arbitrary order (as 
            indicated by the frequent and helpful cross references throughout the text) and 
            succeeds in mapping out his main themes. The personal interests of each reader 
            determine which of the sections may be deemed too detailed and which too 
            sketchy, but considering the need for such a comprehensive overview, the levels 
            are generally appropriate. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The book is, on the one hand, not a light read, and an executive summary might 
            have been possible in a quarter the length. But, on the other, so many of the 
            judgments depend on a subtle interpretation of a multitude of sources that the 
            author is obligated to present the raw data for the reader's inspection. The 
            modular nature of the book also allows a reader to skip, browse, and revisit 
            earlier sections, aided by a convenient internal organization and a thorough 
            index. 
            </p>
            <p>
            First in the world's attention, and in the text, is a discussion of the human 
            victims of the accident. The official tally is 31 (only about 20 names have 
            ever been released), but Marples suspects there were other short-term radiation 
            victims. A large number of unnecessary late-term abortions were also performed 
            on local women, and by rights those unborn babies count as casualties. 
            Widespread "radiophobia" led to restricted diets which created malnourishment 
            and subsequent disease in thousands of people. The tens of thousands of people 
            taking part in cleanup operations were never included in official totals of 
            those exposed. Since the book went to press, Soviet military sources have 
            referred to at least one death in the actual reactor entombment program. 
            </p>
            <p>
            But the greatest toll is likely to occur with the delayed deaths. Here, Marples 
            encounters for the first time the soon familiar theme of official Soviet 
            myth-making around the event: Reality is twisted to serve state policy 
            objectives, which include calming an alarmed public with assurances that all is 
            well when it isn't. 
            </p>
            <p>
            And thus is born what he properly labels the "myth of Chernobyl," the official 
            line that the disaster provided a test that Soviet society passed with honor. 
            "In the Soviet view," he writes, "it was first and foremost a victory, a story 
            with an ending, and an ending that was triumphant." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Thus, when sober Western medical estimates placed the future "excess cancer 
            deaths" at several tens of thousands, both in the Soviet Union and in Europe (a 
            few tenths of a percent elevation of the natural cancer rate), the Soviets 
            reacted furiously. The estimates are branded "nonsense" and the estimators are 
            dismissed as "panic mongers" promulgating "anti-Soviet venom." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Subsequently the author addresses themes of environmental impact, economic and 
            political repercussions, public images, and the recovery operations. Along the 
            way, Marples provides a damning list of examples in which Soviet officials 
            attempted to retreat behind old-style cover-ups and outright lies. False 
            information was issued on radiation levels, on subsequent accidents at the 
            site, on contamination levels of the Kiev water supply, on severe discipline 
            against non-volunteer cleanup personnel, on reactor entombment schedules and on 
            operator training levels. 
            </p>
            <p>
            A severe 1986-1987 countrywide electrical power shortage was officially denied 
            although it was real enough to compel the restart of three Chernobyl reactors 
            in explicit violation of Soviet safety regulations. Design deficiencies of the 
            Chernobyl-style reactors were downplayed and human errors were declared to be 
            the primary culprit. 
            </p>
            <p>
            Ultimately, observes the author, "It is ironic that in an era of openness, 
            Chernobyl may have been both the pioneer of glasnost under Gorbachev and then 
            subsequently its first casualty." He ultimately concludes, "Aspects of the 
            disaster . . . have rarely been dealt with thoroughly or even honestly by 
            Soviet sources." Hence the need for this book, a need which is admirably 
            fulfilled despite the many remaining mysteries and uncertainties. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The July, 1987, trial of reactor personnel marked a full circle of disclosure. 
            Journalists were allowed into the pre-scripted first and last days, but the 
            weeklong deliberative sessions were held in secret and no word of their 
            substance has ever been released. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The propaganda purpose of the trial and surrounding official publicity, he 
            maintains, had one goal: "To divert culpability from the party hierarchy, in 
            Kiev and especially in Moscow." This is precisely the theme I have also 
            encountered in my own investigations of aerospace accidents of the past. Where 
            individual human failings led to catastrophe, a sanitized story may eventually 
            be released, but where Kremlin policy led to disaster (such as the Nedelin 
            catastrophe of 1960 or the Soyuz-1 disaster in 1967), the entire event remains 
            absolutely off limits to glasnost. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The closing blow-by-blow description of the nuclear power debate presages a 
            dramatic event which occurred too recently for inclusion in this first edition. 
            Viktor Legasov, tagged by the author as one of the country's two leading 
            pro-nuclear advocates, actually was sinking into private despair over the poor 
            implementation of safety standards. In the end, he made his final and most 
            eloquent testimony to this despair on the second anniversary of the accident, 
            by committing suicide. For several weeks the Soviets tried to sit on the 
            circumstances of his "tragic death," even issuing official non-explanations 
            which asserted that the death was not due to medical effects of radiation. 
            Finally, crusading journalist Vladimir Gubarev, with access to Legasov's 
            notebooks, broke the story in Pravda. Readers of this book will come to know 
            these and other characters so well that the suicide fits right into the "big 
            picture" of the catastrophe's social impacts. 
            </p>
            <p>
            For an author to so accurately describe a social milieu that subsequent 
            unpredictable events only enhance his insights is testimony to the highest 
            quality of scholarship. Readers of Marples' book will rarely be surprised as 
            the Chernobyl catastrophe's consequences continue to unfold in the future. 
            </p>
            </text>
            <graphic>
            <p>
            Photo, Chernobyl Then and Now :Photographs of the damaged reactor taken before 
            the construction of its concrete "sarcophagus" are, for obvious reasons, aerial 
            photographs. Left, an artist's reconstruction of the reactor as it would have 
            looked from the ground before the sarcophagus was in place. The point of view 
            is the same as that of an official Soviet photograph, right, taken as the 
            entombment neared completion. 
            </p>
            </graphic>
            <type>
            <p>
            Book Review; Main Story 
            </p>
            </type>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0013 </docno>
            <docid> 31 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Book Review; Page 10; Book Review Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            146 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            CURRENT PAPERBACKS: WAITING FOR CHILDHOOD BY SUMNER LOCKE ELLIOTT (PERENNIAL 
            LIBRARY/ HARPER &amp; ROW: $7.95) 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <byline>
            <p>
            By ELENA BRUNET 
            </p>
            </byline>
            <text>
            <p>
            Set in Australia at the turn of the 20th Century, "Waiting for Childhood" is 
            the story of seven children left to cope for themselves after their parents 
            die. Their father, The Rev. William Lord, expires at the breakfast table one 
            morning. After the family leaves for a ramshackle house owned by a wealthy 
            cousin, the mother loses her mind and then her life in an accident. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The eldest daughter, Lily, takes charge of the entire household, as Jess 
            becomes a favorite of her rich cousin Jackie and watches her rival for Jackie's 
            affections fall fatally from a mountaintop. 
            </p>
            <p>
            These characters, "all talented, all deeply human, (are) all so beautifully 
            realized that by the end of the novel we identify with them to the point of 
            heartbreak," Carolyn See wrote in these pages. " 'Waiting for Childhood' 
            manages to be at once terribly melancholy and extraordinarily exhilarating." 
            </p>
            </text>
            <type>
            <p>
            Column; Book Review 
            </p>
            </type>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0032 </docno>
            <docid> 74 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Business; Part 4; Page 3; Column 1; Financial Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            1299 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            VIEWPOINTS; 
            </p>
            <p>
            '89 WISH LIST: PROTECTION, TAXES AND PEACE; 
            </p>
            <p>
            SOCIAL BENEFITS, DEFICIT REDUCTION ARE TOP PRIORITIES FOR THE NEW YEAR 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <text>
            <p>
            What changes would you like to see in business practices and the workplace this 
            year? How can business leaders and economic policy-makers improve the economy 
            and the world in general in 1989? The Times ran these questions by people in 
            various walks of life, and here are some of their answers: 
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            Muriel Siebert, head of the Muriel Siebert &amp; Co. discount brokerage in New 
            York, and first female member of the New York Stock Exchange: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would like to see certain business practices regulated. I think that the 
            leveraged buyouts show the greed of people at their worst. . . . The LBOs are 
            bypassing the purpose of the capital-raising system. I think that to the extent 
            that people were stockholders in these companies . . . they should be allowed 
            to continue to have some kind of share in the profits (after the leveraged 
            buyouts) because these moves were done while they were stockholders. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Must greed be the creed? I would like to see that also rolled over to our 
            defense contractors. I am pro defense. I believe in a strong country because 
            people mistake gentility for weakness. If (contractors) cheat on defense 
            contracts, I don't see why they don't go to jail. . . . I just feel that if you 
            are a major defense contractor, you owe a fiduciary responsibility to this 
            country because defense expenditures are putting a pretty big toll on the 
            country." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Andrew Brimmer, former member of the Federal Reserve Board and head of a 
            Washington economics consulting firm: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "My leading wish is that the nation deal with the federal budget deficit. I 
            would like to see a substantial reduction in 1989 and extending over the next 
            three years. I would strongly recommend that we raise taxes. There should be 
            some moderation in the level of government expenditures, but the real problem 
            is the lag in revenue. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I also would like to see more done for education by business. The kind of 
            education I'm talking about is at the elementary and secondary level. 
            Businesses are already contributing to colleges. Businesses should do likewise 
            for elementary and secondary schools. Business people can play a role as 
            counselors and teachers. A firm might make available an engineer or 
            mathematician to go into schools and teach. Business should do more to offer 
            on-the-job training for unskilled, or limited-skills, people, perhaps through a 
            (lower) learning wage. We would give business tax credits to do this." 
            </p>
            <p>
            William R. Robertson, executive secretary of the Los Angeles County Federation 
            of Labor, AFL-CIO: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would like to see a change in philosophy by the incoming President relating 
            to labor relations and providing for fairness in our (labor) organizing efforts 
            and contract negotiations. . . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would also like to see some protection for workers losing their jobs because 
            of mergers. It is a national disgrace. In too many mergers, the workers are the 
            ones that suffer and the country as well. Something should be done to correct 
            it. . . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            "And, finally, this Administration should face reality in resolving the 
            astronomical deficit." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Steven D. Lydenberg, an associate with the "socially responsible" investment 
            firm of Franklin Research &amp; Development: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "There is an increasing interest around the country in social investing. People 
            want to know not just the financial implications of making a commitment in a 
            company, but also the social implication. That information is not very easy to 
            come by. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "So, if at the end of '89 corporations were disclosing in a uniform way their 
            yield figures, their charitable contribution figures, the numbers of women and 
            minorities in top management and board directors, their attitude on a number of 
            comparable social issues, I would be very happy." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Frank Borman, chairman of Patlex Corp. of Chatsworth, former astronaut and 
            former chairman of Eastern Airlines: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "We should begin to move toward taxing consumption -- a value-added tax. This 
            is quite controversial as Al Ullman (Oregon Democrat and former chairman of the 
            House Ways and Means Committee, who was defeated in 1988 after advocating a 
            value-added tax) will tell you. But this taxing system is needed. It would 
            certainly help our exports. Almost all of Europe is under the value-added 
            taxing system. Also, it may encourage saving instead of consumption. One of the 
            ways you discourage consumption is to tax it." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Michael Harrington, co-chair of Democratic Socialists of America and author of 
            "The Other America" and "The New American Poverty": 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I hope Secretary of State Baker will build on the basic insights of former 
            Treasury Secretary Baker (James Baker, former treasury secretary, was nominated 
            by President-elect Bush to be Secretary of State) that a settlement of Third 
            World debt is in the self-interest of America, opening up markets for business 
            and labor. But then the new Baker will have to go far beyond the old, since 
            Latin America now owes more than it did in 1982 when the crisis officially 
            began, and several countries, including Argentina and Brazil, may see democracy 
            subverted if current trends persist. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "At home, the nation must recognize that we can't waste young people, and 
            particularly minorities and women, on illiteracy, unemployment and unproductive 
            low-wage work. We must invest mightily in education, training and job 
            generation." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Alan Bromberg, a securities law expert and professor at Southern Methodist 
            University: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "There are several things I would like most to see changed in the economy and 
            business practices. One, more concentration by business and government, both 
            here and abroad, on . . . the facilitation of international trade and 
            investment. This would require wider horizons for business people . . . and 
            more effort by government to reduce and ultimately eliminate all kinds of 
            restrictions on the movement of products. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Two, I would like to see a national consensus developed, preferably in the 
            form of federal legislation, on corporate takeovers and buyouts that would 
            recognize the efficiencies and benefits they bring as well as the dislocations 
            and hardships they can cause. This would involve tax policies and labor polices 
            and limitations on the ability of states to Balkanize corporate law by 
            different anti-takeover statutes everywhere. (There also should be) some kind 
            of limitation on management self-entrenchment and self-enrichment. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I think we could use a lot of clarification of the securities laws. I think 
            the courts have done a good job of saying what insider trading is. The kind of 
            issues that are most difficult are what really is parking (of stock)? How much 
            cooperation or similar action by different individuals or different groups of 
            individuals makes it collaboration? These issues haven't been well resolved. . 
            . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            Peter Bahouth, executive director of Greenpeace in Washington: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "People now view threats to human security less in terms of political threats 
            and more in environmental and economic terms. So for my wish list, I would ask 
            first that we deal with the issue of the greenhouse effect. We better develop 
            some alternative views in mass transportation and cut subsidies to reflect the 
            true cost of fossil fuels in terms of pollution, along with the actual economic 
            cost of development. Then, we could put more money into research and 
            development of wind and solar energy. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "(Also on my wish list is) peace on earth. If we want peace on earth, we have 
            to start looking seriously at the fact that we are making more and more 
            weapons, and in a process which endangers the health of American people. . . . 
            Production plants have been proven to have released into the air and water 
            radioactivity and toxic chemicals." 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Also, it would be nice if we could learn that the rain forest affects all of 
            us. We need to preserve it. And we would like the tuna industry to stop killing 
            dolphins." 
            </p>
            </text>
            <graphic>
            <p>
            Drawing, JILL BANASHEK / for The Times 
            </p>
            </graphic>
        </doc>
    </section>

        <section>
            <h2>Raw Text</h2>
            <div class="output1">
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the order of `this.articles` is changing every time you use `appendChild` because `this.articles` is not an array but an HTML Collection.

```js
DOM = {
  output1: document.querySelector('.output1')
};


class TextAnalyzer {

  getArticles = (out) => {
    this.articles = document.getElementsByTagName("text");
  }

  getText = (key) => {
    return this.articles[key];
  }

  getTexts = (out) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      console.log(this.articles)
      out.appendChild(this.articles[i])
    }

  }

  showArticles = () => console.log(this.articles);
}

const analysis = new TextAnalyzer();

analysis.getArticles();
analysis.getTexts(DOM.output1);
```

```css
body {
  background: white
}
```

```html
<text>article 0</text>
<text>article 1</text>
<text>article 2</text>
<text>article 3</text>
<text>article 4</text>

<h2>Raw Text</h2>
<div class="output1">
</div>
```

You can solve this by create an [array from html collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222847/3729184) (i.e. change this line):

```
    getArticles = (out) => {
        this.articles = [...document.getElementsByTagName("text")];
    }
```

```js
DOM = {
    output1: document.querySelector('.output1')
};


class TextAnalyzer {

    
    getArticles = (out) => {
        this.articles = [...document.getElementsByTagName("text")];
    }

    getText = (key) => {
         return this.articles[key];
    }

   
    getTexts = (out) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.articles);
        console.log(keys);
             
        keys.forEach(key => {
            console.log(this.articles[key])
            out.appendChild(this.articles[key])
        })
            
    }

    showArticles = () => console.log(this.articles);
}

const analysis = new TextAnalyzer();
analysis.getArticles();
analysis.showArticles();
analysis.getTexts(DOM.output1);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0001 </docno>
            <docid> 1 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Book Review; Page 1; Book Review Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            1206 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            NEW FALLOUT FROM CHERNOBYL; 
            </p>
            <p>
            THE SOCIAL IMPACT OF THE CHERNOBYL DISASTER BY DAVID R. MARPLES (ST. MARTIN'S 
            PRESS: $35, CLOTH; $14.95, PAPER; 316 PP., ILLUSTRATED; 0-312-02432-0) 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <byline>
            <p>
            By James E. Oberg , Oberg, a space engineer in Houston, is the author of 
            Uncovering Soviet Disasters: Exploring the Limits of Glasnost (Random House). 
            </p>
            </byline>
            <text>
            <p>
            The onset of the new Gorbachev policy of glasnost, commonly mistranslated as 
            openness but closer in connotation to candor or publicizing, has complicated 
            the task of Soviet secret-keepers and has allowed substantial new Western 
            insights into Soviet society. David R. Marples' new book, his second on the 
            Chernobyl accident of April 26, 1986, is a shining example of the best type of 
            non-Soviet analysis into topics that only recently were absolutely taboo in 
            Moscow official circles. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The author, a British-educated historian and economist, is a research associate 
            with the Canadian Institute of Ukrainian Studies at the University of Alberta, 
            and the academic style of the book is undisguised. However, its intended 
            audience is the general public, and anyone interested in nuclear power, or 
            Soviet economy and society, or human drama, or just plain sleuthing state 
            secrets, will find hitherto unpublished revelations and explanations of the 
            event and its continuing aftermath. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The effects of Chernobyl reverberated throughout so many facets of Soviet 
            society that a continuous coherent narrative is probably impossible. Marples 
            discusses half a dozen major themes arranged in a fairly arbitrary order (as 
            indicated by the frequent and helpful cross references throughout the text) and 
            succeeds in mapping out his main themes. The personal interests of each reader 
            determine which of the sections may be deemed too detailed and which too 
            sketchy, but considering the need for such a comprehensive overview, the levels 
            are generally appropriate. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The book is, on the one hand, not a light read, and an executive summary might 
            have been possible in a quarter the length. But, on the other, so many of the 
            judgments depend on a subtle interpretation of a multitude of sources that the 
            author is obligated to present the raw data for the reader's inspection. The 
            modular nature of the book also allows a reader to skip, browse, and revisit 
            earlier sections, aided by a convenient internal organization and a thorough 
            index. 
            </p>
            <p>
            First in the world's attention, and in the text, is a discussion of the human 
            victims of the accident. The official tally is 31 (only about 20 names have 
            ever been released), but Marples suspects there were other short-term radiation 
            victims. A large number of unnecessary late-term abortions were also performed 
            on local women, and by rights those unborn babies count as casualties. 
            Widespread "radiophobia" led to restricted diets which created malnourishment 
            and subsequent disease in thousands of people. The tens of thousands of people 
            taking part in cleanup operations were never included in official totals of 
            those exposed. Since the book went to press, Soviet military sources have 
            referred to at least one death in the actual reactor entombment program. 
            </p>
            <p>
            But the greatest toll is likely to occur with the delayed deaths. Here, Marples 
            encounters for the first time the soon familiar theme of official Soviet 
            myth-making around the event: Reality is twisted to serve state policy 
            objectives, which include calming an alarmed public with assurances that all is 
            well when it isn't. 
            </p>
            <p>
            And thus is born what he properly labels the "myth of Chernobyl," the official 
            line that the disaster provided a test that Soviet society passed with honor. 
            "In the Soviet view," he writes, "it was first and foremost a victory, a story 
            with an ending, and an ending that was triumphant." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Thus, when sober Western medical estimates placed the future "excess cancer 
            deaths" at several tens of thousands, both in the Soviet Union and in Europe (a 
            few tenths of a percent elevation of the natural cancer rate), the Soviets 
            reacted furiously. The estimates are branded "nonsense" and the estimators are 
            dismissed as "panic mongers" promulgating "anti-Soviet venom." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Subsequently the author addresses themes of environmental impact, economic and 
            political repercussions, public images, and the recovery operations. Along the 
            way, Marples provides a damning list of examples in which Soviet officials 
            attempted to retreat behind old-style cover-ups and outright lies. False 
            information was issued on radiation levels, on subsequent accidents at the 
            site, on contamination levels of the Kiev water supply, on severe discipline 
            against non-volunteer cleanup personnel, on reactor entombment schedules and on 
            operator training levels. 
            </p>
            <p>
            A severe 1986-1987 countrywide electrical power shortage was officially denied 
            although it was real enough to compel the restart of three Chernobyl reactors 
            in explicit violation of Soviet safety regulations. Design deficiencies of the 
            Chernobyl-style reactors were downplayed and human errors were declared to be 
            the primary culprit. 
            </p>
            <p>
            Ultimately, observes the author, "It is ironic that in an era of openness, 
            Chernobyl may have been both the pioneer of glasnost under Gorbachev and then 
            subsequently its first casualty." He ultimately concludes, "Aspects of the 
            disaster . . . have rarely been dealt with thoroughly or even honestly by 
            Soviet sources." Hence the need for this book, a need which is admirably 
            fulfilled despite the many remaining mysteries and uncertainties. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The July, 1987, trial of reactor personnel marked a full circle of disclosure. 
            Journalists were allowed into the pre-scripted first and last days, but the 
            weeklong deliberative sessions were held in secret and no word of their 
            substance has ever been released. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The propaganda purpose of the trial and surrounding official publicity, he 
            maintains, had one goal: "To divert culpability from the party hierarchy, in 
            Kiev and especially in Moscow." This is precisely the theme I have also 
            encountered in my own investigations of aerospace accidents of the past. Where 
            individual human failings led to catastrophe, a sanitized story may eventually 
            be released, but where Kremlin policy led to disaster (such as the Nedelin 
            catastrophe of 1960 or the Soyuz-1 disaster in 1967), the entire event remains 
            absolutely off limits to glasnost. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The closing blow-by-blow description of the nuclear power debate presages a 
            dramatic event which occurred too recently for inclusion in this first edition. 
            Viktor Legasov, tagged by the author as one of the country's two leading 
            pro-nuclear advocates, actually was sinking into private despair over the poor 
            implementation of safety standards. In the end, he made his final and most 
            eloquent testimony to this despair on the second anniversary of the accident, 
            by committing suicide. For several weeks the Soviets tried to sit on the 
            circumstances of his "tragic death," even issuing official non-explanations 
            which asserted that the death was not due to medical effects of radiation. 
            Finally, crusading journalist Vladimir Gubarev, with access to Legasov's 
            notebooks, broke the story in Pravda. Readers of this book will come to know 
            these and other characters so well that the suicide fits right into the "big 
            picture" of the catastrophe's social impacts. 
            </p>
            <p>
            For an author to so accurately describe a social milieu that subsequent 
            unpredictable events only enhance his insights is testimony to the highest 
            quality of scholarship. Readers of Marples' book will rarely be surprised as 
            the Chernobyl catastrophe's consequences continue to unfold in the future. 
            </p>
            </text>
            <graphic>
            <p>
            Photo, Chernobyl Then and Now :Photographs of the damaged reactor taken before 
            the construction of its concrete "sarcophagus" are, for obvious reasons, aerial 
            photographs. Left, an artist's reconstruction of the reactor as it would have 
            looked from the ground before the sarcophagus was in place. The point of view 
            is the same as that of an official Soviet photograph, right, taken as the 
            entombment neared completion. 
            </p>
            </graphic>
            <type>
            <p>
            Book Review; Main Story 
            </p>
            </type>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0013 </docno>
            <docid> 31 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Book Review; Page 10; Book Review Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            146 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            CURRENT PAPERBACKS: WAITING FOR CHILDHOOD BY SUMNER LOCKE ELLIOTT (PERENNIAL 
            LIBRARY/ HARPER &amp; ROW: $7.95) 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <byline>
            <p>
            By ELENA BRUNET 
            </p>
            </byline>
            <text>
            <p>
            Set in Australia at the turn of the 20th Century, "Waiting for Childhood" is 
            the story of seven children left to cope for themselves after their parents 
            die. Their father, The Rev. William Lord, expires at the breakfast table one 
            morning. After the family leaves for a ramshackle house owned by a wealthy 
            cousin, the mother loses her mind and then her life in an accident. 
            </p>
            <p>
            The eldest daughter, Lily, takes charge of the entire household, as Jess 
            becomes a favorite of her rich cousin Jackie and watches her rival for Jackie's 
            affections fall fatally from a mountaintop. 
            </p>
            <p>
            These characters, "all talented, all deeply human, (are) all so beautifully 
            realized that by the end of the novel we identify with them to the point of 
            heartbreak," Carolyn See wrote in these pages. " 'Waiting for Childhood' 
            manages to be at once terribly melancholy and extraordinarily exhilarating." 
            </p>
            </text>
            <type>
            <p>
            Column; Book Review 
            </p>
            </type>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <docno> LA010189-0032 </docno>
            <docid> 74 </docid>
            <date>
            <p>
            January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
            </p>
            </date>
            <section>
            <p>
            Business; Part 4; Page 3; Column 1; Financial Desk 
            </p>
            </section>
            <length>
            <p>
            1299 words 
            </p>
            </length>
            <headline>
            <p>
            VIEWPOINTS; 
            </p>
            <p>
            '89 WISH LIST: PROTECTION, TAXES AND PEACE; 
            </p>
            <p>
            SOCIAL BENEFITS, DEFICIT REDUCTION ARE TOP PRIORITIES FOR THE NEW YEAR 
            </p>
            </headline>
            <text>
            <p>
            What changes would you like to see in business practices and the workplace this 
            year? How can business leaders and economic policy-makers improve the economy 
            and the world in general in 1989? The Times ran these questions by people in 
            various walks of life, and here are some of their answers: 
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            Muriel Siebert, head of the Muriel Siebert &amp; Co. discount brokerage in New 
            York, and first female member of the New York Stock Exchange: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would like to see certain business practices regulated. I think that the 
            leveraged buyouts show the greed of people at their worst. . . . The LBOs are 
            bypassing the purpose of the capital-raising system. I think that to the extent 
            that people were stockholders in these companies . . . they should be allowed 
            to continue to have some kind of share in the profits (after the leveraged 
            buyouts) because these moves were done while they were stockholders. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Must greed be the creed? I would like to see that also rolled over to our 
            defense contractors. I am pro defense. I believe in a strong country because 
            people mistake gentility for weakness. If (contractors) cheat on defense 
            contracts, I don't see why they don't go to jail. . . . I just feel that if you 
            are a major defense contractor, you owe a fiduciary responsibility to this 
            country because defense expenditures are putting a pretty big toll on the 
            country." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Andrew Brimmer, former member of the Federal Reserve Board and head of a 
            Washington economics consulting firm: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "My leading wish is that the nation deal with the federal budget deficit. I 
            would like to see a substantial reduction in 1989 and extending over the next 
            three years. I would strongly recommend that we raise taxes. There should be 
            some moderation in the level of government expenditures, but the real problem 
            is the lag in revenue. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I also would like to see more done for education by business. The kind of 
            education I'm talking about is at the elementary and secondary level. 
            Businesses are already contributing to colleges. Businesses should do likewise 
            for elementary and secondary schools. Business people can play a role as 
            counselors and teachers. A firm might make available an engineer or 
            mathematician to go into schools and teach. Business should do more to offer 
            on-the-job training for unskilled, or limited-skills, people, perhaps through a 
            (lower) learning wage. We would give business tax credits to do this." 
            </p>
            <p>
            William R. Robertson, executive secretary of the Los Angeles County Federation 
            of Labor, AFL-CIO: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would like to see a change in philosophy by the incoming President relating 
            to labor relations and providing for fairness in our (labor) organizing efforts 
            and contract negotiations. . . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I would also like to see some protection for workers losing their jobs because 
            of mergers. It is a national disgrace. In too many mergers, the workers are the 
            ones that suffer and the country as well. Something should be done to correct 
            it. . . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            "And, finally, this Administration should face reality in resolving the 
            astronomical deficit." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Steven D. Lydenberg, an associate with the "socially responsible" investment 
            firm of Franklin Research &amp; Development: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "There is an increasing interest around the country in social investing. People 
            want to know not just the financial implications of making a commitment in a 
            company, but also the social implication. That information is not very easy to 
            come by. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "So, if at the end of '89 corporations were disclosing in a uniform way their 
            yield figures, their charitable contribution figures, the numbers of women and 
            minorities in top management and board directors, their attitude on a number of 
            comparable social issues, I would be very happy." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Frank Borman, chairman of Patlex Corp. of Chatsworth, former astronaut and 
            former chairman of Eastern Airlines: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "We should begin to move toward taxing consumption -- a value-added tax. This 
            is quite controversial as Al Ullman (Oregon Democrat and former chairman of the 
            House Ways and Means Committee, who was defeated in 1988 after advocating a 
            value-added tax) will tell you. But this taxing system is needed. It would 
            certainly help our exports. Almost all of Europe is under the value-added 
            taxing system. Also, it may encourage saving instead of consumption. One of the 
            ways you discourage consumption is to tax it." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Michael Harrington, co-chair of Democratic Socialists of America and author of 
            "The Other America" and "The New American Poverty": 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I hope Secretary of State Baker will build on the basic insights of former 
            Treasury Secretary Baker (James Baker, former treasury secretary, was nominated 
            by President-elect Bush to be Secretary of State) that a settlement of Third 
            World debt is in the self-interest of America, opening up markets for business 
            and labor. But then the new Baker will have to go far beyond the old, since 
            Latin America now owes more than it did in 1982 when the crisis officially 
            began, and several countries, including Argentina and Brazil, may see democracy 
            subverted if current trends persist. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "At home, the nation must recognize that we can't waste young people, and 
            particularly minorities and women, on illiteracy, unemployment and unproductive 
            low-wage work. We must invest mightily in education, training and job 
            generation." 
            </p>
            <p>
            Alan Bromberg, a securities law expert and professor at Southern Methodist 
            University: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "There are several things I would like most to see changed in the economy and 
            business practices. One, more concentration by business and government, both 
            here and abroad, on . . . the facilitation of international trade and 
            investment. This would require wider horizons for business people . . . and 
            more effort by government to reduce and ultimately eliminate all kinds of 
            restrictions on the movement of products. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Two, I would like to see a national consensus developed, preferably in the 
            form of federal legislation, on corporate takeovers and buyouts that would 
            recognize the efficiencies and benefits they bring as well as the dislocations 
            and hardships they can cause. This would involve tax policies and labor polices 
            and limitations on the ability of states to Balkanize corporate law by 
            different anti-takeover statutes everywhere. (There also should be) some kind 
            of limitation on management self-entrenchment and self-enrichment. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "I think we could use a lot of clarification of the securities laws. I think 
            the courts have done a good job of saying what insider trading is. The kind of 
            issues that are most difficult are what really is parking (of stock)? How much 
            cooperation or similar action by different individuals or different groups of 
            individuals makes it collaboration? These issues haven't been well resolved. . 
            . . 
            </p>
            <p>
            Peter Bahouth, executive director of Greenpeace in Washington: 
            </p>
            <p>
            "People now view threats to human security less in terms of political threats 
            and more in environmental and economic terms. So for my wish list, I would ask 
            first that we deal with the issue of the greenhouse effect. We better develop 
            some alternative views in mass transportation and cut subsidies to reflect the 
            true cost of fossil fuels in terms of pollution, along with the actual economic 
            cost of development. Then, we could put more money into research and 
            development of wind and solar energy. 
            </p>
            <p>
            "(Also on my wish list is) peace on earth. If we want peace on earth, we have 
            to start looking seriously at the fact that we are making more and more 
            weapons, and in a process which endangers the health of American people. . . . 
            Production plants have been proven to have released into the air and water 
            radioactivity and toxic chemicals." 
            </p>
            <p>
            "Also, it would be nice if we could learn that the rain forest affects all of 
            us. We need to preserve it. And we would like the tuna industry to stop killing 
            dolphins." 
            </p>
            </text>
            <graphic>
            <p>
            Drawing, JILL BANASHEK / for The Times 
            </p>
            </graphic>
        </doc>
    </section>

        <section>
            <h2>Raw Text</h2>
            <div class="output1">
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```