# Javascript HTMLCollection to array using slice. Why does it work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, slice

Haii so I've recently used converting `HTMLCollection` to array in order to use the `filter` method and that by doing `Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlcollection).filter(...);` from a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) answer but I can't figure out 2 things:

1. `Array.prototype.slice(htmlcollection).filter(...);` won't work
2. How can a `HTMLCollection` use an array method

Finally I'd like to create this behavior in my own classes so I can call `Array.prototype.slice.call(new MyClass()).filter(...);`

Thanks in advance for your generous contribution and time

Comment: #1 Because `slice` doesn't take the array to slice as an argument. #2 HTMLCollection is an iterable object, the language is designed so, that iterable objects can be sliced. ES6+ has [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method, maybe you don't need to implement your own class for this ..?

Comment: @Teemu Why htmlcollection.slice() won't work?? if HTMLCollection is an iterable

Comment: Because [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object doesn't have `slice` method. The key why `Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlcollection)` works is [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which sets the collection as `this` to `slice`, and the slicing can be performed.

Comment: So you're saying doing [1, 2, 3, 4].slice() is different from Array.prototype.slice.call([1, 2, 3, 4]) ??

Comment: Basicly yes, the former uses the method from the array instance directly, in the latter, the method is used statically from the prototype. Please read what is written about `call` at MDN, the article is linked in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Array.from()` method

[Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)