# How do I add an addEventListener to my div element targeted with getElementsByClassName in my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, event-listener, getelementsbyclassname

How do I add an `addEventListener` scroll to my `div` element? Currently I have below, but I get a Typescript ESLint error:

> Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type
> 'HTMLCollectionOf'.ts

```
const Overlay = ({ children }: Props) => {
  // const [fade, setFade] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document
      .getElementById('dialog')
      ?.getElementsByClassName('MuiDialog-paperScrollPaper');
    console.log(element);

    const onScroll = () => {
      console.log('Scrolled');
    };
    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog fullScreen open={open} id="dialog">
        <header id="header">
          // My header
        </header>
        {children}
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Overlay;
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array. Not an element.

Comment: I'd advise you to use `onScroll` handler on `DialogContent` instead

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName('MuiDialog-paperScrollPaper')`

This returns a collection (HTMLCollection) not a single element

Next, read this to map or loop through the collection (to add your event listener to each found element:
[Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)