# Convert HTMLCollection to an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, classname, htmlcollection

I want to get all the HTML elements with the class "Box" and then that collection convert it to an Array so i can acces each element throught position.

This is the code i made:

```
function BoxAppearence() {
    
    var BoxCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("Box");
    console.log(BoxCollection)
    var Box = BoxCollection.split("");
    console.log(Box)
    
    console.log(Box[12])
}

BoxAppearence();
```

Comment: `var BoxCollection = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("Box"));` should do what you want

Comment: This is my code rn:
```
function BoxAppearence() {
    
    var Box = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("Box"));
    console.log(Box);
    console.log(Box[12]);
}

BoxAppearence();
```
But in console it's shows: [] and undefined

Comment: As you can see in this [JSFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/uvfagkd5/), it works; are you sure you provided the correct class name (remember JavaScript is case-sensitive and "Box" is not the same as "box")? Are you sure your page contains elements with the "Box" `class`? Are you sure you are executing the function *after* the DOM has completely loaded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array)

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in the comment, you can convert your HTML collection to an array by using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Anyway, if your only reason for converting the collection to an array is being able to access an element by its index/position, as you can see from the code snippet below, you can do it also with an HTML collection (although actually you would be using an object "key" rather than an index).

```js
function BoxAppearence() {
  var BoxCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("Box");
  var BoxArray = Array.from(BoxCollection);
  
  console.log("### BoxCollection ###");
  console.log("Is 'BoxCollection' an array?", Array.isArray(BoxCollection));
  console.log(BoxCollection);
  console.log(BoxCollection[12])
  console.log('\n\n');
  console.log("### BoxArray ###");
  console.log("Is 'BoxArray' an array?", Array.isArray(BoxArray));
  console.log(BoxArray);
  console.log(BoxArray[12]);
}

BoxAppearence();
```

```html
<div class="Box">box1</div>
<div class="Box">box2</div>
<div class="Box">box3</div>
<div class="Box">box4</div>
<div class="Box">box5</div>
<div class="Box">box6</div>
<div class="Box">box7</div>
<div class="Box">box8</div>
<div class="Box">box9</div>
<div class="Box">box10</div>
<div class="Box">box11</div>
<div class="Box">box12</div>
<div class="Box">box13</div>
```