# Foreach not works on html collection

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname

I have two files, one of js:

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

const d = a.getElementsByTagName("h1");

d.forEach(element => {
   element.innerHTML = "the text has changed";
});
```

and html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>David
</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello1</h1>
    <h2>david</h2>
    <h3>ariel</h3>
    <h4>yahav</h4>
    <h1>hello2</h1>
    <h1>hello3</h1>
    <script src="food.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to change the text of each h1 element to the same text, but it's not working, meaning when i run it on the broswer, all the "h1" texts remains the same.

not sure why, because "d" is an html collection, and i run on it with the foreach.

Basically everything stright forward, so not sure what i could try.

appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) doesn't implement a `forEach` method. You'll need to use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, [convert it to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) first, or use a [query method that returns a NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: please remove the screenshots of text and add the text instead

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use `forEach` because HTMLCollections don't implement a forEach method.

Use the for loop

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
const d = a.getElementsByTagName('h1')

for (let elem of d) {
    elem.innerHTML = 'new text'
}
```

Comment: please vote to close either as duplicate or as not reproducable. `forEach` is also implemented by `NodeList`, `Set` and `Map` as well as `Array` with additional implementations for `DOMTokenList`, `KeyboardLayoutMap`, `Headers` etc...

Comment: (also `console.log(typeof d)` is a meaningless check as everything in js is an object including arrays `console.log(typeof []); // "object"`)

Comment: @pilchard Oh, sorry, you're right, I just wanted to help a person with a problem. I tried to explain why in this particular case it won't work. Do you think it would be correct to delete this answer ?

Comment: It's a fine answer, but just correct 'because it's an array method' to 'because HTMLCollections don't implement a forEach method' to make it accurate at least. But in general basic questions like this are best redirected to the documentation, to the numerous duplicates that answer it, or closed as not reproducable.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I'll be more careful next time!

Comment: Answer is not right

Comment: I think you can try to play it to make sure it works